# Environment decorators

Tags: macros, environments

I'm looking for a way to write a "decorator" (in Python terminology) or a "wrapper" for LaTeX environments: a way to give addition behaviour with save of the notation. For example, before every `\begin{quote}` execute a code that will add a `\hrule`.

I could make it for a single command using `\let`:

```
\let\oldCommand\commandIWantToDecorate
\def\commandIWantToDecorate#1{<addition code>\oldCommand{#1}}
```

That will execute `<addition code>` without the need to change the command throughout the document.

Is there a similar way to decorate the whole environment? Maybe LaTeX creates some inner macros I can work with?

**UPD** the question [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself) doesn't solve my problem, because I'm interested in redefining environments, not solo macros.

[The `etoolbox` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467438/178377) partly solve the problem, thanks [@samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)!

But in "education" reasons I'm interesting is there a way to do decorate without additional packages, using just (La)TeX pre-build commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: By the way, your `\let` - version above would work for the environment starter macro as well, unless it has optional arguments -- then problems will appear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel provides `\g@addto@macro` which works for the environment starter command as well, i.e. for the environment `quote` the start macro is `\quote`, so say `\g@addto@macro\quote{foo}` etc.

No extra packages are needed for this, apart from the specific additions that are to be made, but that depends on  personal choices of the O.P, but in general 'anything' can be placed in `\g@addto@macro\quote{...}`.

```
\let\oldquote\quote
\renewcommand{\quote}{fooaddition\oldquote}
```

would work as well, but this may fail for other environments that have optional arguments. In this case, `\LetLtxMacro` from `letltxmacro` package is needed, which means another package, however.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\quote{\hrule
  \medskip

  \textit{be careful}

  \medskip

  Now the real stuff begins\dots

}
\makeatother    

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
test
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the `etoolbox` package, in particular to its `\AtBeginEnvironment` command. This allows you to add aditional code to the begin of environment.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\hrule}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
test
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```