# How to fix the size of variable-size operators

Tags: size, renewcommand, scalerel

When using variable-size operators such as `\prod`, `\sum`, `\bigcup`, and `\bigcap`, their sizes are usually not quite predictable, which makes me pretty annoyed. I just want to make their sizes fixed throughout the document, e.g., the same vertical size as `X_{1}^{1}`.

I tried to renew the definition of `\prod` using `\renewcommand` and *scalerel* package:

```
\renewcommand{\prod}{{\scalerel*{\prod}{X_{1}^{1}}}}
```

but it throws an error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]. \prod
```

It should be allowed to use `\limits` to put limits on the top and bottom of the symbol in display mode.

Any comment on this issue?

**Edit:**

I prepared an example demonstrating the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\set}[2]{\left\{{#1}~\middle|~{#2}\right\}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}
        =
        \set{x \in A\to \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}}{\forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}}
    \end{equation*}

    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{r@{~}l}
            \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}
            &=
            \set{x \in A\to \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}}{\forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}}\\
            &=
            \set{x \in A\to \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}}{\forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}}
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}

    The above two equations show the inconsistent sizing of operators.

    \newcommand{\prode}{\mathop{\scalerel*{\prod}{X_{1}^{1}}}}
    \newcommand{\bigcupe}{\mathop{\scalerel*{\bigcup}{X_{1}^{1}}}}

    The desired result is
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{r@{~}l}
            \prode\limits_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}
            =
            \set{x \in A\to \bigcupe\limits_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}}{\forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}}
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the last equation, I defined `\prode` and `\bigcupe`. But I just want to renew `\prod` and `\bigcup`. I think the error is caused by infinite loops.

**Found solution:**

I solved the problem by using `\let` found in [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47353/142888)

```
\let\oldprod\prod
\renewcommand{\prod}{\mathop{\scalerel*{\oldprod}{X_{1}^{1}}}}
\let\oldbigcup\bigcup
\renewcommand{\bigcup}{\mathop{\scalerel*{\oldbigcup}{X_{1}^{1}}}}
```

Thank you!

Comment: On what basis do you rest your claim that the "sizes [of `\sum` and `\prod`] are usually not quite predictable"? FWIW, as long as you understand the difference between display math mode and inline math mode, there's absolutely nothing unpredictable about the sizes of `\sum` and `\prod`.

Comment: what do you mean by not predicatable?  `\sum` (and all the others) come in exactly two sizes, one for textstyle inline math and one for displaystyle. what is annoying you about that? Your redefinition is defining `\prod` in terms of itself so is an infinite loop, but the definition is not necessary.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that generic question: there are sum subtle points here that make applying those methods awkward.

Comment: @egreg I agree but someone flagged this as a duplicate...

Comment: @Hermis14 Let's wait for it to be reopened. In the meantime, I warn you against defining `\set` that way: the size of the braces and of the middle bar is way too big.

Comment: @egreg In fact *scalerel* works as expected except that it does not apply consistently both to the inline math and display mode.

Comment: @Hermis14 And the “solution” you came up with is very suboptimal.

Comment: you are misusing `array` which is intended for typesetting matrices and sets its content in _inline_ mode if you used display math the operators would be display size in all cases and you would not be tempted to use \scalerel`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's a very important point I was not aware of... Thank you! Then, should I use the `split` environment in place of `array`?

Comment: `aligned` see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size *is* predictable and it follows the typographic traditions.

Anyway, here's a way to reduce the size in display style to be the same as in text style.

I take advantage from the fact that big operators are defined in a uniform way by `amsmath`, using a common template and the operator `\xyz` refers internally to `\xyz@`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\reduceoperators}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \hermis_reduceoperator:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hermis_reduceoperator:n
 {
  \cs_set_eq:cc { latex@#1@ } { #1@ }
  \cs_set_protected:cpx { #1@ }
   {
    \mathop
     {
      \mathchoice
      {\textstyle\use:c{latex@#1@}}
      {\use:c{latex@#1@}}
      {\use:c{latex@#1@}}
      {\use:c{latex@#1@}}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\reduceoperators{sum,prod,bigcup,bigcap}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\tag{samples}
\sum\prod\bigcup\bigcap
\\[4ex]
\tag{good}
\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} =
\bigl\{x \in A\to \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}
  \bigm| \forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}\bigr\}
\\
\tag{bad}
\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} =
\Bigl\{x \in A\to \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}
  \Bigm| \forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}\Bigr\}
\\
\tag{ugly}
\prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} =
\left\{x \in A\to \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}
  \;\middle|\; \forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}\right\}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to save the meaning of `\sum@` into `\latex@sum` and then redefining `\sum@` to mean

```
\mathop\mathchoice{\textstyle\latex@sum@}{\latex@sum@}{\latex@sum@}{\latex@sum@}
```

so in display style we actually use the `\textstyle` version. With the help of `expl3` trickery, we're able to do all the needed redefinitions at once with no code duplication.

I also take the occasion to show how your definition of `\set` with `\left` and `\right` is not really good. For the expression you have `\big` size is more than enough: already `\Big` size is too much.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> The above two equations show the inconsistent sizing of operators.

The inconsistency is due to the misuse of the `array` environment which is not designed for displayed equations, but for typesetting matrices: it sets its content in textstyle not displaystyle.

If you use a display alignment then the operators use a consistent style.

[image]

However the delimiters here are far too large. You can modify the set command to take an optional size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}


\newcommand{\set}[3][]{\mathopen{#1\{}{#2}~#1|~{#3}\mathclose{#1\}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}
        =
        \set[\Big]{x \in A\to \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}}{\forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}}
    \end{equation*}

    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{aligned}
            \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha}
            &=
            \set[\Big]{x \in A\to \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}}{\forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}}\\
            &=
            \set[\Big]{x \in A\to \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_{\alpha}}{\forall \alpha \in A: x_{\alpha} = x(\alpha) \in X_{\alpha}}
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your answer, too, especially for handling the size of the delimiter and braces of a set. The comment on the difference between `array` and `aligned` is also nice. I wish I could have chosen both answers!

Comment: @Hermis14 when in doubt between me and egreg then naturally there is a right choice and a wrong choice:-)