# Which latex editor is able to access all documentation of all packages?

Tags: documentation

I am looking for an editor or documentation browser that can look up all commands from all packages, for eg I want to for 'whiledo' then I want a window or pane to pop up with the required reference information. Also one forgets the command so it would be helpful to type in 'loop commands' and a list of possible commands is displayed.

`texdoc` does not do this as it requires a package name.

The Perl pod browser works in this way.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: This is not exactly a question about editors, as it is not up to the (La)TeX editor to manage documentation for packages. Moreover, (La)TeX documentation is simply not in the single format that Perl requires for pod: you are not be able to look at documentation for an arbitrary Perl module using pod, only ones with documentation in the required format. TeX documentation takes a number of forms, and while most is now available as PDF files, the way the sources are set up depends entirely on the person who wrote it.

Comment: there is no such editor

Comment: @JosephWright Still, it is a good question. It would be possible to index or `\def`, `\let` and similar commands from all macros, at least to make a list of references to the correct packages. Then you can automate the documentation finder and download the correct PDF file if it's not already on the computer. I know, you get plenty of false positives, but there shouldn't be much of such that does not contain `@` for start.

Comment: @tohecz I did not say it was a bad question :-) Indexing is not so straight-forward, I suspect. One of the LaTeX3 concerns is trying to have a more structured approach to document and programming commands, so I not uninterested in this.

Answer (score 1):

Also not a complete answer, but if you use

```
find /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/source/ -name "*.dtx" -exec grep -q "\\\DescribeMacro{.*whiledo.*}" {} \; -print | xargs -n 1 basename | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'texdoc "${0%.dtx}"'
```

in a unixoid shell (of course, you should have sources installed and you need to put in the right path to your distribution) the documentation of the ifthen package will pop up.

For regular use you'll wish to make a shell script named, for instance `lookuptexdoc.sh` containing

```
#!/bin/bash

find /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/source/ -name "*.dtx" -exec grep -Eq "\\\DescribeMacro{.*$1.*}|\\\DescribeEnv{.*$1.*}" {} \; -print | xargs -n 1 basename | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'texdoc "${0%.dtx}"'
```

Then by calling `lookuptexdoc.sh comment` you'll get the documentation of all packages defining a command or environment whose name contains "comment".

This can be much refined of course, I'm not a skilled shell programmer by far.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a complete answer, but under linux, it is easily possible to find a `.sty` file (i.e. package) that contains `\def`, `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\gdef` or `\let` followed by the macro name. For example the following shell command sucessfully returns that the macro `\linenumbers` is defined in the file `lineno.sty`. Just, you might need to modify number of `\` at different places of the shell command depending on your linux settings.

```
grep -l '\\\(def\|edef\|let\|gdef\|xdef\)\\linenumbers[^a-z@]' \
`find /usr/share/texmf -regex '.*\.sty\|.*\.cls'`
```

Of course, you might happen to get more positive files, e.g. the command `\tag` is defined in 4 different files and the macro `\reserved@a` is defined plenty of times because it is a popular local "macro variable" name.

Comment: the problem comes from tex syntax.  quite apart from \newcommand \providecommand ... \DeclareRobustCommand, there's the weird usages like \csname and delimited commands and...  it's just too much!  (i've tried this as a possible help mechanism, and given up because there seems little value in the results i've got.)

Comment: I know ... There are more commands like these, e.g. `\[re][provide]newenvironment`. But I think that it needn't be that complicated, most front-end commands are defined in some standard way, `\csname` is used mostly for inner commands where you need some data storage or reference.

Comment: By `grep`ing for `\DescribeMacro` and suchlike in the `.dtx` files you'd get far less false positives (and more false negatives :-) But as this question is about documentation it's sensible to assume that the macro under consideration should at least be 'officially' documented.

Comment: @StephanLehmke ... considering the package was documented by `.dtx` and this was done correctly...

Comment: @StephanLehmke as well, `.dtx` files are not in every distro...

Comment: As I said, more false negatives... But still, hereabouts `find /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/source/ -name "*.dtx" -exec grep -q "\\\DescribeMacro{\\\newcolumntype}" {} \; -print | xargs -n 1 basename | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'texdoc "${0%.dtx}"'` (probably clumsy, but the first I could think of) gives me the documentation of three packages defining `\newcolumntype`. And that's a lot more than texdoc alone gives.