# How to search for the commands in TeX

Tags: macros, tex-core

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined)
>   [Macro find tool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57340/macro-find-tool)

When I am reading the other's `LaTeX` codes, I always find new commands I have never read before of.

Is there any method to search for the command I want to know?

Comment: Looking in the preamble to see if it's defined by the author or searching in google/here.

Comment: for anyone interested,[LaTeX Reference Manual](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/*checkout*/latexrefman/trunk/latex2e.pdf), alternatively you can type at the command prompt   `texdoc latex2e` for `LaTeX`  and `texdoc texbytopic` for `TeX` and Prof Knuth's `TeX82` book by `texdoc tex`.  for more info [Which books can I read via texdoc ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27636/15717).

Comment: Also related: [Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined) and [How to find out where a macro is defined?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/how-to-find-out-where-a-macro-is-defined)

Comment: some good suggestions in the question [Is there a printable version of a reference manual for all TeX primitives?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/)