# References for \dimexpr \numexpr

Tags: calculations, dimensions

I'm not really sure whether this is the right place to ask this question, but here I go....

Over the holiday I've been taking time to read through a lot of the Q&A here.  I've been running across some  TeX code (or maybe LaTeX code) that I cannot find either in *source2e* doc or Knuth's *The TeXbook*.  Where can I find documentation that explains `\dimexpr` and `\numexpr` and their syntax?

Comment: Somewhat special case of [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/). -- (side note, for this one e-TeX manual is quite dense in general, so maybe see also [units - Simple explanations for \dimexpr and dimensions in general - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367361/simple-explanations-for-dimexpr-and-dimensions-in-general))

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These are primitives which are not present in Knuth's TeX but which were added as part of the e-TeX extensions. As such, they are documented in the [e-TeX manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etex), which is most conveniently accessed using `texdoc etex`.