# Centering text body and margin notes together

Tags: geometry

With `geometry`, I want to center text body and margin notes together, namely to center `textwidth + marginparsep + marginparwidth` parts of horizontal elements.

I think one option would be to include margin notes into `total body` by `includemp` and center the `total body`. But that would screw up the current layout of my document and I have to adjust `hscale` all over again.

So how could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set one of the margins to be *short* by `\marginparsep + \marginparwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paper=letterpaper,
  margin=2in,
  inner=\dimexpr2in-\marginparsep-\marginparwidth,
  twoside,% Optional
  showframe% Just for this example
}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \marginpar{This is a margin paragraph.}
Cras a lorem eget mauris sagittis vehicula et nec nunc. 
Phasellus pulvinar purus nec risus varius, quis mollis mi porta.

\newpage

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \marginpar{This is a margin paragraph.}
Cras a lorem eget mauris sagittis vehicula et nec nunc. 
Phasellus pulvinar purus nec risus varius, quis mollis mi porta.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Werner. It solved my question. I also found reference [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88344/references-for-dimexpr-numexpr) for the `\dimexpr` primitive you used in your solution.