# Using powers in \dimexpr

Tags: lengths

The code

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{\dimexpr 1.2^{3} 10pt}{\dimexpr 1.2^{3} 10pt}\selectfont Hello TeXworld.
\end{document}
```

does not work. Why not?

**EDIT:** I need a solution that supports all integral (including *negative*) exponents.

Comment: Beyond 'this is not valid syntax for a `\dimexpr`' I'm not sure what you are after here as an answer! (See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88344/references-for-dimexpr-numexpr)

Comment: Obviously, I would like someone to correct it to the right syntax. ;-)

Comment: You can also check out the Expression section in `texdoc etex`, which says `An expression consists of one or more terms of
the same type to be added or subtracted; a term of type t consists of a factor of that type, optionally multiplied and/or divided by numeric factors; finally a factor of type t is either a parenthesized subexpression or a quantity (number, etc.) of that type.`

Comment: apart from dimexpr not having any syntax for power you don't have any multiplication symbol `\dimexpr 1.2 10pt` would not work either

Comment: No, but from what I gathered by looking around, it seemed that the multiplication symbols was not used when multiplying lengths by non-integral numbers. Hence I hoped that the `}` in front would convince TeX that there was an implicit multiplication symbol in front. Can't say I ever really believed it would work, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

e-TeX's `\dimexpr` only allows a very limited range of items inside the expression. In particular, you can only multiply a dimension by an integer value

```
\dimexpr 10pt * 5\relax
\dimexpr 10pt * (5 * 5)\relax
```

Note the fact that the dimension here comes first. As is the case for a TeX register, you can multiply a `\dimexpr` by a real number by placing it before the expression

```
1.2\dimexpr 10pt * 5 \relax
```

Thus for your case you will need a series of expressions, each multiplied by 1.2, or to pre-calculate the factor

```
\dimexpr1.2\dimexpr1.2\dimexpr1.2\dimexpr 10pt \relax\relax\relax\relax
\dimexpr 1.728\dimexpr 10pt\relax
```

An alternative approach would be to use the `expl3` FPU to do the floating point work, for example

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \fptodim \fp_to_dim:n 
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

then one of

```
\dimexpr\fpeval{1.2^(3)}\dimexpr 10pt\relax
\dimexpr\fptodim{1.2^(3) * 10}\relax
```

where the latter uses the fact that the conversion of a float to dimen uses points as the unit. Note that this method supports negative exponents:

```
\the\dimexpr\fpeval{1.2^(-3)}\dimexpr 10pt\relax % => 5.78703pt
\the\dimexpr\fptodim{1.2^(-3) * 10}\relax        % => 5.78703pt
```

Comment: Is `\cs_new_eq:NN` the recommended way of populating Expl macros?

Comment: @yo' You could use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpeval}{m}{\fp_eval:n{#1}}`

Comment: @yo' For the case here of creating a couple of expandable document commands which are equivalent to `expl3` code level ones there is not much in it between this and `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Comment: Yes, I know it supports negative exponents. Excellent answer, by the way! I'm currently using your answer. But it never hurts to get David's answer to work for the purpose as well. I plan to keep the acceptance of your answer anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You need to encode powers as a macro but a simple recursive loop should do the trick

+ve

```
===: \dimexpr 1.2\dimexpr 1.2\dimexpr 1.2\dimexpr 10pt\relax \relax \relax \relax 
===: 17.27985pt
```

-ve

```
===: \dimexpr \dimexpr (\dimexpr (\dimexpr (10pt * 100)/120 \relax  * 100)/120 
\relax  * 100)/120 \relax \relax 
===: 5.78703pt
```

Log output from

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\def\powerfactor#1#2#3{%
\ifnum#2=0
\dimexpr#3\expandafter\relax
\else
\afterfi
\powerfactor{#1}{\numexpr#2-1\relax}{#1\dimexpr#3\relax}%
\fi}
\def\afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}

\def\negpowerfactor#1#2#3{%
\ifnum#2=0
\dimexpr#3\expandafter\relax
\else
\afterfi
\negpowerfactor{#1}{\numexpr#2-1\relax}{\dimexpr(#3 * 100)/\twodp#100.{}{}! \relax}%
\fi}
\def\twodp#1.#2#3#4!{#1#2#3}

\typeout{===: \powerfactor{1.2}{3}{10pt}}
\typeout{===: \the\powerfactor{1.2}{3}{10pt}}
\typeout{===: \negpowerfactor{1.2}{3}{10pt}}
\typeout{===: \the\negpowerfactor{1.2}{3}{10pt}}

\begin{document}

{\fontsize{\powerfactor{1.2}{3}{10pt}}{\powerfactor{1.2}{3}{10pt}}\selectfont Hello TeXworld.\par}

{\fontsize{\negpowerfactor{1.2}{3}{10pt}}{\powerfactor{1.2}{3}{10pt}}\selectfont Hello TeXworld.\par}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer! The only thing is (and I should have said this in the first place) I also want negative (but still integral!) exponents. Is this possible?

Comment: @Gaussler yes you just have to spot the negative value  (otherwise recursing by subtracting one until you get to 0 may take a while) and code it as repeated division. Exercise for the reader?:-)

Comment: Yes, I guessed as much. I was mostly concerned about breaking your fancy `\afterfi` method. But it worked out just fine. :-)

Comment: Is there no way to do a non-rounded division?

Comment: @Gaussler `\dimexpr 10pt * 10 / 12 \relax`

Comment: @Gaussler updated with negative powers