# Convert decimal to integer in Visual TeX IDE

Tags: calculations

I want to convert decimal number to integer in latex program with Visual Tex IDE. I found this function `\pgfmathparse{ceil(2.7)}` which requires installing the package `pgfmath` and `pgfkeys`. And after conversion I need to add two numbers. I tried using `\numexpr` (for integers) and `\dimexpr` (for decimals). But both functions simply concatenate those two values.

I don't know how to install packages in Visual Tex. Could someone suggest me how to install a package in Visual TeX. Or Could someone suggest me if there is any other function in `calc` package through which I can get ceil.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{calc}%
\begin{document}%
\newcommand{\addnum}[2] {%
  \def\numa{#1}
  \def\numb{#2}
  \def\deca{#3}
  \def\decb{#4}
  Int Sum is \numexpr\numa+\numb\relax
  Dec Sum is \dimexpr\deca+\decb\relax
}%%
\addnum{10}{20}{30.45}{55.63}%
\end{document}%
```

It gives below output:

> Int Sum is 10+20
>   Dec Sum is 30.45+55.63

This program works in MiKTeX. But I want it to work on Visual Tex IDE. I set the output mode as PDF.

Comment: I'm not familiar with 'Visual TeX  IDE': can you provide a link?

Comment: Below links have information regarding Visual Tex(VTEX) IDE:
http://www.micropress-inc.com/texdocs/enide.htm
http://www.micropress-inc.com/

Comment: Ah: VTeX. We had this come up recently. VTeX hasn't been updated for about 10 years and doesn't have the e-TeX extensions, which provide for example `\numexpr`.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239560/undefined-control-sequence-in-vtex, where someone else seemed to run into much the same issue.

Comment: @JosephWright Does l3int use eTeX?

Comment: You get either the error message `Undefined control sequence` or `You can't use `\numexpr' in vertical mode`.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, since e-TeX was finalised in 1999 we do require it.