# Why we used \number in Latex?

Tags: dimension-expressions

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\Printdimen#1#2{\strip@pt \dimexpr #2 *65526 /\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Printdimen{mm}{\hsize} mm
\end{document}
```

Comment: _all_ your questions seem to be about this one line of code?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah , because i am confused about that

Comment: @egreg but  after /  i used \dimexpr 1#1

Comment: @enadulshaheen You've asked several questions about one code line which suggest you don't really know the details of the TeX treatment of numbers/dimensions. This is quite low-level stuff and is best learned by reading something like _TeX by Topic_ plus [some stuff on e-TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88344/references-for-dimexpr-numexpr).

Comment: But just asking the same question repeatedly in multiple question sand in chat gives the impression that you ignore the answers.

Comment: Actually i am new to latex thats why need to clear conception. Thanks all of them for answering my question.

Comment: @enadulshaheen We've already pointed out that this is not really the sort of code that one reads to learn LaTeX. Even if you aim to learn to program plain TeX you should pick up some basics first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro `\strip@pt` wants after it a dimension register; it will remove the final `pt` after the extracted value.

In e-TeX, `\dimexpr` behaves as an “unnamed” dimension register, so it's good after `\strip@pt`. According to the syntax rules of `\dimexpr`, a dimension (implicit or explicit) inside it can be followed by `*` or `/` to denote multiplication or (rounded) division. However the multiplier/divisor *must* be an integer.

So `\dimexpr 3pt/2` is valid, but `\dimexpr3pt/1.5` is not.

A dimension register appearing in a context where TeX expects an integer will be coerced to it using the value in scaled points; 65536 scaled points are 1pt, which is the reason for the 65536 multiplier.

Thus `\number` is not really necessary and

```
\makeatletter
\def\Printdimen#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr (#2) * 65536 / \dimexpr 1#1\relax\relax}
\makeatother
```

is good as well. It's better to add the two `\relax` that end the `\dimexpr` expression.

Comment: perfect answer man . I got it what i need. Thanks

Comment: I would add parentheses around `#2`, then this argument can be any expression understood by `\dimexpr` without invalidating the multiplication.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Good idea!