# PsPicture inside tabular

Tags: tables, pspicture

When using PsPicture inside a `tabular`, aligning the picture to the top works fine using `\raisebox{}` as shown in tabular no. 1. I archieved additional space under the picture using `\vspace`. (Is there a better way to do it???)


Now, I would like to align a formula inside the left cell at the bottom while a PsPicture is located in the right cell. As shown in tabular no. 2, row no. 1, it works fine. But I intend to add a small space above the PsPicture using `\vspace` again. Unfortunately, the aligning of the text at the bottom works no more. How can I get the required space above the picture *and* align the formula to the bottom?


[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.47\textwidth}|D{0.47\textwidth}|}
\hline
Formula & 
\raisebox{-\height+0.5\baselineskip}{
\begin{pspicture}
\psframe(0,0,)(6,5)
\end{pspicture}}\vspace{0.1cm}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|b{0.47\textwidth}|D{0.47\textwidth}|}
\hline
Formula &
\begin{pspicture}
\psframe(0,0,)(6,5)
\end{pspicture}\\\hline
Formula & \vspace*{0.1cm}
\begin{pspicture}
\psframe(0,0,)(6,5)
\end{pspicture}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

- use `booktabs` and `no vertical rules`: the rules of booktabs have  some vertical (adjustable) padding around them. The table xwill look more professional;
- use `\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+some length]` to fool LaTeX and make it believe the figure height is slightly larger than its natural height.

Here is an example of both solutions:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{tabular}{b{0.47\textwidth}D{0.47\textwidth}}
\toprule
Formula &
\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+5pt]{\begin{pspicture}
\psframe(0,0,)(6,5)
\end{pspicture}}\\\midrule
Formula &
\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+5pt]{\begin{pspicture}
\psframe(0,0,)(6,5)
\end{pspicture}}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|b{0.47\textwidth}|D{0.47\textwidth}|}
\hline
Formula &
\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+5pt]{\begin{pspicture}
\psframe(0,0,)(6,5)
\end{pspicture}}\\\hline
Formula &
\raisebox{0pt}[\dimexpr\height+5pt]{\begin{pspicture}
\psframe(0,0,)(6,5)
\end{pspicture}}\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution, thank you very much. What is the function of `\dimexpr`?

Comment: It's an etex primitive: it makes arithmetic operation on lengths. There are similar `\numexpr` and `\glueexpr`. It should end  with `relax` (which I didn't have to do because of the `]` at the end. You may  look at this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245635/formal-syntax-rules-of-dimexpr-numexpr-glueexpr) on this site for more details.

Comment: So far so good, but is it really necessary? I removed the `\dimexpr`and got the same result ... Just a coincidence?

Comment: It's. You load `calc`, and I prefer to use the etex primitives. Without cal, or \dimexpr, it won't work. B.t.w., I forgot to remove calc loading.

Comment: New problem: If I have a pspicture in the left and the right cell (see on top, same picture instead of "formula"), how can I shift the pictures different? For example, left picture 5pt as shown above, but right picture 3cm? Using `raisebox{0cm}[\height+5pt+3cm]` on the right picture shifts **both** pictures 3cm instead of just the right one ...

Comment: I have some difficulty to see what you mean precisely. Could you post some sketch (hand-made) explaining it visually?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54104/discussion-between-gotti91-and-bernard).

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/gURcs.jpg]

Comment: @Gotti: I've posted a code fragment in chat.

Answer (score 0):

Use coordinates for `pspicture`! And if you need negative coordinates, then use the option `shift` for moving it up.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pst-all}    
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{b{0.47\textwidth}D{0.47\textwidth}}\toprule
Formula & \begin{pspicture}(6,5.1) \psframe(6,5)\end{pspicture}\\\midrule
Formula & \begin{pspicture}(6,5.1) \psframe(6,5)\end{pspicture}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|b{0.47\textwidth}|D{0.47\textwidth}|}\hline
Formula & \begin{pspicture}(6,5.2)\psframe(6,5)\end{pspicture}\\\hline
Formula & \begin{pspicture}(6,5.2)\psframe(6,5)\end{pspicture}\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So I guess it's `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}` for PDFLaTeX then?

Comment: `crop=off` is only needed when no Perl is installed. However, use `xelatex` and you do not need `auto-pst-pdf`.

Comment: I see. Using no coordinates for `pspicture` has been a quite comfortable ... no need to test out as every picture had the right "dimensions" ... additionally no cropped corners, seems to have been done by the package `auto-pst-pdf` itself ... But why is it so important to use the coordinates?

Comment: without specifying coordinates, it takes always `(10cm,10cm)` which makes only sense when images are cropped!