# Define numeric variable in terms of another variable

Tags: automation, variable

So, I have a variable called `number` which I define like so:

```
\def\number{0.25}
```

I'd like to automatically define a number which will give me `1-number` (in this case, which would give me `0.75`). I tried doing this:

```
\def\othernumber{1-\number}
```

However, this didn't seem to work. It seems like the engine doesn't realize that I want to subtract `\number` from `1`. Could anyone help me fix this syntax? Thanks :)

Comment: `\def\number{0.25}` is a very bad thing to do: `\number` is a TeX primitive. Can you tell something more about the usage of these macros?

Comment: Oh, whoops. I just put that there – I probably wouldn't have used such a generic term. Let's say it's `\spanvalue` instead. Also, hello!

Comment: Depending on what you want to use the numbers for, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245635/formal-syntax-rules-of-dimexpr-numexpr-glueexpr may be useful.

Comment: Note that when you say `\def\spanvalue{0.25}`, you should not read it as “`\spanvalue` is now equal to the number 0.25”. This is not what happens; `\def` is meant for text substitution, and what happens is that TeX simply records the *replacement text* for the macro`\spanvalue` as being the sequence of tokens `0`, `.`, `2` and `5`. TeX does have some rudimentary support for arithmetic, but `\def` (or even `\newcommand` in LaTeX) is not it. And the support from packages like `xfp` and `pgf` (as in the answers) is much greater.

Comment: Ohh, now I understand! That definitely clears up why I'm having these problems. Thanks a lot for explaining!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pgf` package for this. Instead TeX primitive `\def` one need use `\pgfmathsetmacro`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\first}{0.25}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\second}{1-\first}

The value of \verb|\first| is \first

The value of \verb|\second| is \second
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `\pgfmathsetmacro` will happily redefine existing commands without any warning.

Comment: and remember to cast as `int` if you are trying to use integers, e.g. `\pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{int(\k+1)}` to set `\j` equal to `\k+1`

Answer (score 9):

You can use `xparse` and `xfp` (the latter allows computations on the fly):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineconstant}{mm}
 {
  \cs_new:Npx #1 { \fp_eval:n { #2 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\defineconstant{\constantA}{0.25}
\defineconstant{\constantB}{1-\constantA}
\defineconstant{\constantC}{round(sqrt(\constantA),2)+\constantB/2}

The value of \verb|\constantA| is \constantA

The value of \verb|\constantB| is \constantB

The value of \verb|\constantC| is \constantC

\fpeval{round(\constantA-\constantC+exp(2),4)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the power of l3