# How to do arithmetic with variables used in for loop?

Tags: foreach, variable, arithmetic

How can I use arithmetic inside a node's curly brackets? I have this, and it prints for example "0+1" in a circle. I would like to have circles that show the sum of their coordinates.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3}
\draw [] (\x,\y) circle [radius=0.4] node {\x + \y};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Chapter VIII of the Tikz manual is devoted to the mathematical engine... You should find there all you need. Basically, look for `pgfmathparse`, `pgfmathresult` and company.

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371868/define-numeric-variable-in-terms-of-another-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this simple case where only integers are involved you can do the arithmetic using `\numexpr`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
\foreach \y in {0,1,2,3}
\draw [] (\x,\y) circle [radius=0.4] node {\the\numexpr\x + \y\relax};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

But there must be some TikZ way.

Note: `\numexpr` is available since 2004 by default with pdflatex with TeXLive distribution. But there is not much of user level documentation I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5}
        \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\z{int(\x+\y)}
        \draw (\x,\y) circle [radius=0.4] node {\z};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

If you change this line:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\z{int(\x+\y)}
```

in this line:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\z{\x+\y}
```

the output is:

[image]

(Note: forget the border lines!)