# using division to calculate column size

Tags: tables, longtable, columns, calculations

I am converting from another format and creating tables with varying numbers of columns.  I would like the column to be approximately layed out.  If there are two columns, I want each column to get half the space.  Something like this:

```
\begin{longtable}{ p{\textwidth/2}  p{\textwidth/2} }
```

That is, for two columns, I want to divide the textwidth by two.  Documentation elsewhere suggests that division should be possible using the forward slash character.

However, what I get is that both columns are the size of the full textwidth, and each cell starts with "/2".  It is as if the /2 is being interpreted as "default text" to put in every cell, even the title row cells.  See below:

[image]

Very strange.  Every example I can find on the web has column width done by multiplying the textwidth by a decimal number.   But that is inconvenient for me: When I have three columns I want it to be divided by three, and so on.   I don't have the decimal for that fraction readily available.

Any idea what to do to get division working?

Comment: Just a guess, but try with `\dimexpr\textwidth/2`.

Comment: Why don't you use package `ltablex` or `xltabular`?

Comment: @Bernard - I have quite an investment in longtable having switched a couple years ago from tabular.  It has specific features I need.  To investigate ltablex or xltabular would require doing a detailed comparison to make sure it meets the other requirements.  There are so many packages to use, but that is more of a problem than a solution.

Comment: `ltablex`brings the functionalities of `longtable`  to  `tabularx` (same syntax). As  to the more recent `xltabular` it loads `ltablex` but does not redefine `tabularx` to avoid some of its drawbacks.. On the whole, if you know how to manage `longable` there should be no difficulties in using one of those packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always in TeX (with no extra package) multiply a dimension register by a decimal number:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{.2\linewidth} | p{.25\linewidth} | }
  a & b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use syntax with slash for division, wrap it in `\dimexpr`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{\dimexpr\linewidth/5\relax} | p{\dimexpr\linewidth/4\relax} | }
  a & b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Inside `\dimexpr` you can also do additions etc..., but the syntax `0.2*\linewidth` is as illegal with it as it was with original Knuth TeX. You must not use the `*` at this location. The advantage of `\dimexpr` is to allow things such as

```
\dimexpr0.2\linewidth+3\tabcolsep-0.9876\dimexpr15pt\relax+\textwidth/25\relax
```

Notice that for some years now, the pdflatex format builds only on a pdftex which has the e-TeX extensions, inclusive of `\dimexpr`.

The `calc` package dates from an earlier era. You may still use it for some of its facilities such as  `\widthof`, and chances are some package you use still loads it. It does not bring any computational facility that `\dimexpr` does not offer: none of them allow you to compute square roots for example (and computing a square root raises the question of the unit of your dimension).

The `xfp` solution is definitely overkill for adjusting by hand some column dimensions using multiplications and additions, but if you do need powers or square-root this is natural choice (there are other packages doing such computations).

Comment: Do you have any idea why the "/2" then appears in every cell?  Is that expected behavior?

Comment: I did not check the full details but if you try  `\dimen0=\dimen4/2` (using TeX primitives) you will get that the dimension stored in TeX dimension register number 4 is copied in to dimension register number 0, and then `/2` is part of the typeset stream.

Answer (score 5):

By default you can only use minimal calculation within length settings, specifically multiplication (like `0.5\textwidth` or `0.3\linewidth`). As such, using `\textwidth/2` wouldn't work out-of-the-box. If you want to use that, then you'll need [e-TeX's `\dimexpr`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245635/5764):

```
\dimexpr\textwidth/2\relax
```

The trailing `\relax` is optional, depending on the use-case.

The process is automated by the [`calc` package](//ctan.org/pkg/calc) which updates LaTeX com­mands `\set­counter`, `\ad­dto­counter`, `\setlength` and `\ad­dtolength` to take arithmetic arguments. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{\linewidth/5} | p{\linewidth/4} | }
  a & b
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{\linewidth/5+10pt} | p{\linewidth/4-10pt} | }
  a & b
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you want to perform more complex arithmetic on lengths, I'd suggest using [`xfp`](//ctan.org/pkg/xfp). `xfp`'s `\fpeval` converts lengths to `pt` and strips that dimension when performing calculations. So, one would typically use `\fpeval{<length calc>}pt` to specify a length. Here's another example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{\fpeval{\linewidth/5 - 4^2}pt} | p{\fpeval{sqrt(3^3) + \linewidth/4}pt} | }
  a & b
\end{tabular}

\hspace*{\fpeval{\arrayrulewidth+\tabcolsep}pt}%
\rule{\fpeval{\linewidth/5 - 4^2}pt}{1pt}%
\hspace{\fpeval{2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}pt}%
\rule{\fpeval{sqrt(3^3) + \linewidth/4}pt}{1pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice--learnt something new