# spread across a line (minus indent)

Tags: spacing, indentation, width, textwidth, column-width

I have a sentence I wanted to spread across a line like the following:

`\makebox[\linewidth][s]{XXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XX XXX XXX XX XXXXX XXXXX}\par`

What really happens is because it's a new paragraph with indent, it goes over the margin like the following

[image]

So the question is how do I spread the XXX across a line subtracting the indent space? Note that I still want the indent at the beginning.

Comment: Does adding `\noindent` before `\makebox` help?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I still want the indent, it's a new paragraph

Comment: Well, `\linewidth+\parindent>\linewidth` if `\parindent>0`. Do you want `\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent]...`?

Comment: Well, it worked, do you think it would make sense to make an answer? or I can update the question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is completely up to you. If you think that it is worthwhile to have an official answer, I will be happy to write one.

Comment: Please. It's gonna be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the `\parindent` before the box, you need to subtract it from the `\linewidth` to have a box that fits on the page. Subtracting the width is as simple as saying

```
\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent
```

as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
XXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XX XXX XXX XX XXXXX XXXXX
XXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XX XXX XXX XX XXXXX XXXXX\par

\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent][s]{XXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XX XXX XXX XX XXXXX XXXXX}\par

\end{document}
```

The `\dimexpr` "command" (it is a so-called primitive) is nicely explained in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245635/194703), as are most of its cousins. AFAIK their creator is also co-responsible for the Breitenlohner-Freedman bound.

Comment: actually, can I ask what is exactly ```\dimexpr```

Comment: @user1935724 `\dimexpr` allows us to do simple arithmetics with lengths without introducing an new length. One can build linear combinations of lengths with this. If you want to print the result, use `\the\dimexpr....`, e.g. `\the\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent` will print `415.00462pt` in the above document. Likewise, `\numexpr` allows us to do simple arithmetics with integers. See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245635/194703) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the first line of a paragraph, rather than a stand-alone line. On that assumption, I'd say: Don't set the width at all! just put `\linebreak` at the end of the first-line content. But my assumption is probably not correct, and the answer should *NOT* be to end the text with `\linebreak\par`!

Also, the original `\noindent` suggestion by the hard-to-pin-down feline is fine. Using it means you don't need to calculate width. Just put the indent inside the box

```
 \noindent\makebox[\linewidth][s]{\indent XXX XXXXX XXXXX ... XXXXX}\par
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want a paragraph with the line stretched full width, you can specify that directly by setting `\parfillskip` (the space added to the last line) to 0pt. There is no need for calculations or explicit boxing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
XXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XX XXX XXX XX XXXXX XXXXX
XXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XX XXX XXX XX XXXXX XXXXX

{\parfillskip=0pt
XXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XX XXX XXX XX XXXXX XXXXX

}

\end{document}
```