# What exactly is \dimexpr?

Tags: dimensions

I've seen `\dimexpr` used in the context of setting the width of the columns of a two-column table:

```
\newlength\q
\setlength\q{\dimexpr .5\textwidth -2\tabcolsep}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{|p{\q}|p{\q}|}
...
```

However, I am not sure what `\dimexpr .5\textwidth -2\tabcolsep` means here because I don't know what `\dimexpr` means. I've found the question [formal syntax rules of \dimexpr \numexpr \glueexpr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245635/formal-syntax-rules-of-dimexpr-numexpr-glueexpr), but it doesn't explain what `\dimexpr` is.

Comment: `\dimexpr` evaluates an expression involving dimensions.

Comment: It enables you to make arithmetic operations on dimensions. This was introduced by eTeX.

Comment: So `\dimexpr .5\textwidth -2\tabcolsep` evaluates to `0.5 * \textwidth - 2 * \tabcolsep`?

Comment: @Bernard Sounds like an answer

Comment: @HenriMenke Sounds like an answer

Comment: @mhdadk: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Small note: One should put a `\relax` after the expression one wants to evaluate using `\dimexpr` (and friends) to stop parsing. Most of the time this doesn't hurt, but could result in unwanted behaviour if one forgets the `\relax`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: And if you need the evaluated dimension in text rather than as an internally stored length, use `\the\dimexpr...`.  Here, `\the` causes the internal length that follows to be typeset as a string.  This is useful sometimes when you need to store the dimension for later use or visual inspection.  p.s. `\dimexpr` stands for "dimensional expression".

Comment: To follow up, `3\dimexpr2pt+1pt\relax` would equal the internal representation of 9pt, whereas `3\the\dimexpr2pt+1pt\relax` would equal the string `33pt` (i.e., a `3` concatenated with `3pt`).

Comment: The OLD way of doing it was `\q=0.5\textwidth \advance\q by -2\tabcolsep`.

Comment: @John is it no longer possible to do this?

Comment: You can still do it.  It's sort of like writing in assembly language (one operation per line of code).  The only thing is that you can only \multiply or \divide dimens with counts.

Comment: Anyone know why I can't use `\dimexpr` like this: `\dimexpr{...}`? I get a "missing number, treated as zero." error. However, I get no errors if I write `\dimexpr(...)`.

Comment: @mhdadk: because that's not the syntax of how `\dimexpr` should be used (you linked to a question at the end of your post; this is explained in that post). If you want to visually delimit the arguments to `\dimexpr`, you should follow Skillmon's suggestion and write `\dimexpr .... \relax`.