# Parametrization of the column width in the tabular environment

Tags: tables, lengths

I want to set the parameter `\xx` to define the tabular below.

However, I do not know how to expand the term `(1-\xx)` so the code below does not compile. I would appreciate your help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\def\xx{0.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{\xx\linewidth}p{(1-\xx)\linewidth}}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245635/formal-syntax-rules-of-dimexpr-numexpr-glueexpr and look up tabularx

Comment: thanks @likethevegetable but the line `\begin{tabular}{p{\xx\linewidth}p{\the\dimexpr(1-\xx)\linewidth\relax}}` produces the error message *Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).*

Comment: This isn't the answer you're exactly looking for, but in situations like this, the `tabularx` package is great. Include it, and then specify the total tabular width and use an X column to fill the table to width like so: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ p{\xx\linewidth} X }`

Comment: Well, that is the problem with minimal examples. I need something that works when we have more than 2 columns. Thanks, anyways.

Comment: You can specify multiple X columns and their proportions. (ie one is half as wide as the other, but total fills up linewidth)..read the manual it's a very helpful package designed to help with problems like this.

Comment: I want to create many tables in a document where all the columns will use certain proportions depending on some parameters like `\xx`. If I want to change the values of all the tables in the document, I do not need to make the changes manually on every column of every table. I will be able to just assign values to a few parameters. That is what I need. That can be done with `tabular` or `tabularx`, it does not really matter to me which one I use. The important point is how to expand expressions like `(1-\xx)` inside the options of `tabular` or `tabularx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `xfp` package's `\fpeval` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xfp}
\def\xx{0.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{\xx\linewidth}p{\fpeval{1-\xx}\linewidth}}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But I'd go for a solution that uses tabularx

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\def\xx{0.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ p{\xx\linewidth} X }
a&b\\
c&d
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

If you're going to use these columns many times throughout your doc (like you mentioned in the comments), I would recommmend defining a column with the `array` package, eg.  `\newcolumntype{P}{\xx\linewidth}`