# Why is \char not expandable?

Tags: tex-core, expansion, plain-tex

`\char<number>` is a TeX primitive that results in the character of ASCII code `<number>` with category code 12. However, it isn't expandable, unlike it's many cousins `\romannumeral`, `\number`, etc.

From my understanding, `\char` does not look up upper/lowercase/catcode tables, like `\uppercase` and `\lowercase`, so I'm confused as to why it unexpandable. (I'm not really sure if this is related at all, but I remember from the top of my head that it's the case for `\upper/lowercase`)

Comment: @Mico No, there are a bunch that are expandable, e.g. `\expandafter`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467360/is-there-a-list-of-expandable-tex-primitives-latex-e-tex-others

Comment: `\char` accesses a slot in a font and the glyphs at these slots are not necessarily representable in 8-bit encoding in a meaningful way. It's different for Unicode, where all characters are representable in UTF-8 encoding which is why `\Uchar` in LuaTeX *is* expandable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

luatex and xetex provide `\Uchar` that is expandable

Note that tex has a built in mapping between external character encodings and the internal character codes, and `\char` access the latter so if `\char` expanded to a character token and files were written out and read back (for tables of contents etc) then the behaviour would be different to the current non-expandable behaviour as the characters would be re-mapped (incorrectly, most likely)

Comment: I would also mention `\char_generate:nn` of `expl3` that also works with pdftex.

Answer (score 3):

Only for additional information.
You can define expandable `\echar{number}` by this code in `pdftex`:

```
\def\hex#1{\ifcase\numexpr#1\relax 0\or 1\or 2\or 3\or 4%
   \or 5\or 6\or 7\or 8\or 9\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\fi}
\newcount\tmpa  \newcount\tmpb
\def\echar{}
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\xstring{\expandafter\xstringA\string}  \def\xstringA#1{}
{\endlinechar=-1
   \loop
      \edef\tmp{\noexpand\xstring\xstring\\^\string^\hex\tmpb\hex\tmpa}
      \scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter\edef\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\tmp}}
      \global\expandafter\addto\expandafter\echar\expandafter{\tmp\noexpand\or}
      \advance\tmpa by1\relax
      \ifnum\tmpa=16 \tmpa=0 \advance\tmpb by1 \fi
      \ifnum\tmpb<16 \repeat   
}
\edef\echar #1{\noexpand\ifcase\noexpand\numexpr#1\relax\echar\noexpand\fi}
```

This code creates `\echar` as macro, roughly speaking:

```
\def\echar#1{\ifcase#1^^00\or ^^01\or ^^02\or ... \or ^^fe\or ^^ff\fi}
```

where all tokens between `\or` have category like after `\string`.

Comment: yes, the latex format has a command pre-defined essentially like this, `\char_generate:nn` (the second argument specifying a catcode)

Comment: It seems to be only academical discussion. Unicode engines have primitives `\Uchar` and `\Ucharcat` and there is no reason to use `pdftex` today. My code above shows that things are more complicated if somebody sticks on `pdftex`.

Comment: yes char_generate:nn is \Ucharcat when it is there and a big \ifcase as you show in 8bit tex's

Answer (score 3):

David Carlisle already has explained why `\char` should be unexpandable.

However, there are cases in which an expandable version is handy and `expl3` has the facility available. Here is a plain TeX version (needs an e-TeX engine such as `pdftex`, `xetex` or `luatex`).

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \expchar #1 { \char_generate:nn { #1 } { 12 } }
\cs_new:Npn \xexpchar #1 #2 { \char_generate:nn { #1 } { #2 } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\edef\test{\expchar{92}}
{\tt\meaning\test}

{\tt\test}

\catcode`/=13 \def/{abc}

\xexpchar{47}{13}

\bye
```

[image]

With LaTeX one has a better facility (the category code can be given as an optional argument)

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\expchar}{O{12}m}
 {
  \char_generate:nn { #2 } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ttfamily

\edef\test{\expchar{92}}
\meaning\test

\test

\begingroup
\catcode`/=13 \def/{abc}

\edef\test{\expchar[13]{47}}
\meaning\test

\test
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]