# Plain TeX online documentation/references?

Tags: fonts, tex-core, plain-tex, documentation

I am a non-beginner plain TeX user, mostly typesetting cheat sheets for computer science. I own *The TeXbook* and have seen some TeX manuals for the compilers, such as pdfTeX manuals and so forth.

My problem is that I struggle to find online information whenever I want to find out more about some macro that is not working, or some specific fine point of TeX typesetting. (For example today, I needed to learn more about `\fam` and how to typeset bold fonts in math mode, and it took me a while before I learned which commands to use and how.)

The major problem with searching for plain TeX information is that 90% of information I find through Google search are relevant to LaTeX and not plain.

Are there any good online documents/websites in English that describe in detail finer points on plain TeX? List built-in macros, recommended practices (many people define their own variation on optional variables in macros), and so on?

As an example of literature that I look for, I have found [TeXbook naruby](ftp://math.feld.cvut.cz/pub/olsak/tbn/tbn.pdf), which is a book in Czech about TeX and lists its base macros with examples and explanations. I would like to find comparable literature/website in English for plain TeX.

Comment: These might be of help to you: [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic), and for quick cheat sheet, [TeX ref-card](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/ReferenceCards/TeXRefCard.v1.5.pdf)

Comment: @SuffixTreeMonkey If the difficulty experienced with getting comfortable with the "detail finer points on plain TeX" is caused not just by a lack of knowledge of resources such as a variant in English of the Czech "Texbook naruby" or TeX by Topic, but also by a difficult in getting a conceptual grasp of plain TeX then I recommend [_A Beginner's Book of TeX_ by Raymond Seroul and Silvio Levy](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-1-4419-8654-2%2F1.pdf).  (Although I prefer the paperback version, I believe there is also a Kindle version.)

Comment: As a side note, I have noticed that on `TeXLive 2013` the error messages are the ones from `LaTeX` even when one compiles in Plain TeX mode; not that I care much about this, but it's annoying at times.

Answer (score 11):

Most people using plain TeX build up their own approaches to things, probably starting by reading *The TeXbook* and/or other sources such as the excellent [*TeX by Topic*](http://texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic) (which focusses mainly but not exclusively on primitives). I don't think there is a dedicated 'plain only' website, but you can of course [ask here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), tagging [plain-tex](/questions/tagged/plain-tex) or perhaps [tex-core](/questions/tagged/tex-core) (questions about primitives fall into the latter category).