# Dummies Guide to TeX as a programming language

Tags: documentation

There are a lot of answers that are using a somehow cryptic syntax that I am not familiar with. Is there any Not So Short Introduction to TeX (like Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX) ?!

Comment: There actually is a [Not so short introduction to LaTeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english)...

Comment: There's also the book [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) by Victor Eijkhout, if you're really keen on getting to know the ins and outs of TeX as a programming language. Victor Eijkhout has also written the book [The Computer Science of TeX and LaTeX](http://www.eijkhout.net/texsci/index.html), available online as well, for still more in-depth analysis of TeX and LaTeX from computer science perspective.

Comment: At least related: [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668/5049)

Comment: These comments should probably be answers.

Comment: @lhf - Victor Eijkhout has provided an answer. :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My book "TeX by Topic", which is strictly about TeX, not LaTeX, is available

1. as a free download, including sources
2. from lulu.com, nicely printed

Definitive reference for the locations of all this:

EDIT: new URL: https://eijkhout.net/tex/tex-by-topic.html

Victor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, Victor! It's great to have you on this forum.

Answer (score 5):

**WORK IN PROGRESS:** [texprogramming-persian](https://github.com/vafa/texprogramming-persian) is the ultimate reference for anyone interested in TeX programming, written in Persian. I have finished writing it on paper and I just have to typeset it which may take between 2--3 months considering my limited time resources. It is licensed under GPL version 3 and I have used several references for it including TeX by Topic and TeXBook.

Comment: There are at least five username named 'Vafa Khaligi' in TeX.SE. Are all belong to author of XePersian?! http://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=khalighi

Comment: The link is broke. ◕︵◕