# texdef script shows nothing for chapter

Tags: macros, environments, texdef

Following up [this excellent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined), I've tried to find the definition of the `\chapter` command via

```
 texdef -t latex -f chapter -s
```

It shows then the following output:

```
\chapter:
undefined
```

While for other commands, it works fine, e.g. for `\section` etc.

```
texdef -t latex -f section -s
```

giving the output

```
% article.cls, line 302:
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

It also works fine for `\part` etc.

What is wrong?

Comment: you need -c book to get the definition of \chapter for the book class, it seems to default to the latex format + article class (where \chapter is not defined) so nothing is wrong, it is correctly telling you that \section and \part are defined but \chapter is not (using the default article class)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yeah, I should have read the help page. I tried `man texdef` but forgot about `texdef --help`. You want to put an answer, or  you think this question should rather be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `-c book` to get the definition of `\chapter` for the book class, it seems to default to the latex format + article class (where `\chapter` is not defined).

So nothing is wrong, it is correctly telling you that `\section` and `\part` are defined but `\chapter` is not (using the default article class)

Comment: Thank you again. May I edit the question to include an follow up? I was wondering if I can use `texdef` to find how a specific document uses the `\chapter` definition. So can I give a file `mydocument.tex` as argument to `texdef`?

Comment: @jjdb ive never used texdef, but I think not but you could of course use  `-c` and specify whatever class the document uses.

Comment: So one should probably then try first the class, then all packages one uses… could be some work, though… probbably better to use this approach https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4348/28751