# How to register callbacks in lualatex?

Tags: luatex

Please help me how to register callbacks in lualatex. For example, I need to determine when the page of my document was started or ended and the print number of that page*2. I found in the luatex documentation only how to catch when the end of the page, but it does not work for me. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode}
function f()
tex.print("page "..\thepage*2)
end
id,error=callback.register("finish_pdfpage",f)
tex.sprint(error," ",id)
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
test
\newpage
new test
\end{document}
```

But when I compile this document in lualatex, I get the following errors:

```
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109:
Module luatexbase Error: Attempt to use callback.register() directly
(luatexbase)             on input line 14

stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109: in function 'modu
le_error'
        C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:116: in function 'luat
exbase_error'
        C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:320: in function 'regi
ster'
        [\directlua]:4: in main chunk.
\luacode@dbg@exec ...code@maybe@printdbg {#1} #1 }

l.14 \end{luacode}
?
```

Please also help me to catch the event when a new page is started, e.g. to print the number of this page*2 or the simple number of this page. Thank everybody for help.

Comment: the ltluatex code used by latex (based on an earlier luatexbase package)  implements an allocation scheme for callbacks so different packages can access the callbacks without over-writing each other, but to make that work the primitive callback registration has to be hidden.

Comment: you can use `texdoc ltluatex` to see the documentation latex lua interface. You register a callback with `luatexbase.add_to_callback` as shown in Ulrike's answer.

Comment: I tryed use texdoc ltluatex,but it give me some useful information about callbacks,but not so mutch about the tex functions and attributes of tex tables such as: tex.attribute tex.count tex.dimen tex.skip tex.toks etc,. It seems,that i must guess al this attributes. 

Comment: For the tex.* just use the raw LuaTeX interface documentation (`texdoc luatex`).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `luatexbase.add_to_callback`. But you shouldn't try to print something in `finish_pdfpage`. Here an example that writes to the log:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{luacode}
function f()
texio.write_nl("HELLO: page "..tex.count["c@page"]*2)
end
id,error=luatexbase.add_to_callback("finish_pdfpage",f,"finish")
\end{luacode}
\begin{document}
test
\newpage
new test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok,now it print number of page,but it seems for me,that it print at the second page. How i can catch end of the page and print information about it and how i can catch a start of new page and print information about it and,if it possible,how i can get content only for this pages? It also not understandeble for ne,how i can get the name of callback,which call my function,because in future i want to use one function with several callbacks. Thanks very mutch everybody for the help.