# What does these commands do all together

Tags: color, fancyhdr, thesis

The university gave us a standard tex file for our thesis, and they made it based on Scientific Workplace.

When I opened it with MikTex, many problems occured. I fixed most of them and I'm left with this one :

```
\fancyhf{} \cfoot{\thepage} \lhead{Conclusion} \setlength{\headheight}{0.5cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.7pt}\
```

i don't understand its role.

A second thing is that I used `\usepackage{xcolor}` but unable to use the command `\color{Blue}` as it says that it's undefined

Thrid thing is that my Table of contents has some red squares surrounding titles, how can I remove them  ?

These are the packages I used

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please read the documentation of package `fancyhdr` ...

Comment: @Mensch How can I see the documentation of any file ?

Comment: `texdoc fancyhdr` proably works or online at texdoc.net

Comment: You can download the manual from https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en although you probably already have a copy (somewhereP.  Basically they set up a header and footer for `\pagestyle{fancy}`.  For Blue, use `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}`.

Comment: the red squares around the text are link borders. You could change e.g. use colors instead with \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}. Or you could set the link border to 0. By default xcolor doesn't define a color `Blue`, only `blue`.

Comment: Recently I wrote an answer explain how to make sense of some given code. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621577/250119 (hope it's useful...)

Comment: Oops, `Blue` is also in `svgnames`.

Comment: Thank you all for help ! I started taking control of it :)