# Designing a custom section title frame with a cut in the top border for text input

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, titlesec

I've largely been borrowing the headers (and everything else) as defined in course `.sty` files. I've definitely been confused as to how to make the following:

[image]

It is a frame but has an (optional) gap in between where text input is inserted as well as other text inputs. Basically, the section header should look like so:
[image]

I'd like to know how to create a similar frame and how I can recreate and design similar headings of my own, mostly with respect to the dynamic frame and custom text inputs. If someone knows how to do this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Sorry for the previous troubles with confusing question title.

Comment: This is too many questions in one... what exact part of which header do you want to reproduce? (box with section? Bold text? "Heightened" text? Half-aligned text line? Black bar?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - those are just examples. If you could, Maybe the first one - the box with Lecture # and Lecture Topic as well as date would be a good one to start with.

Comment: Do you have their source code? It may be easier to just look at them to see how it's done.

Comment: I found source code but the problem still stands - I tried taking the source code and editing it myself to no luck. I'll post it if it helps and maybe someone can help explain it to me.

Comment: The code that you show is missing many things that we would need to try it. The first bunch of code is related to `\section` but the second lot is related to footers. Nothing you show seems to be related to headers (at the top of a page). Nothing in the code you showed had anything to do with TikZ.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if it is made with TikZ or if it's made some other way or how and why it works. This is why I'm asking for help and why I thought having source code wouldn't help any more than just graphical descriptions. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Revise As i said, there is no TikZ code in what you showed so everything was made without TikZ.

Comment: @Revise I recently wrote a generic answer on how to understand some code you come across https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/621577#621577 . Hope it helps (and if it doesn't I'd like some feed back too)

Comment: Also perhaps change the title to "How can I make the section title a frame with a cut in the top border for some text" or something, and there doesn't have a MWE either.

Comment: Edited title and descriptions. That'll probably help make more sense and bring a better answer. Really appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regarding your second block of code. It is a revision of the `myheadings` page style.
```

However I think it might better be called something else, perhaps `course`?

```
This code sets up the text for odd and even page footers

    \def\oddfoottext{\begin{footnotesize}\coursenumber, \semester, \title \hfill\qquad\thepage\end{footnotesize}}
    \def\evenfoottext{\begin{footnotesize}\thepage \hfill\qquad\coursenumber, \semester, \title\end{footnotesize}}
    
Now defining the pagestyle.

    \newcommand{ps@course}
    %\def\ps@myheadings{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo % use nothing from sectional divisions
    \def\@oddfoot{\oddfoottext}%      footer text on odd pages
    \def\@evenfoot{\evenfoottext}%    footer text on even pages
    \def\@evenhead{}\def\@oddhead{}}% empty odd and even headers
    
    %\pagestyle{myheadings}          % use the `myheadings` page style
    \pagestyle{course}               % use the `course` page style
```

The code you quote is from a package. If you wanted to use it in a document then surround it with `\makeatletter... \makeatother`

The code is essentially how the page styles are defined in the LaTeX kernel.