# How mapping works in transliteration?

Tags: mapping, transliteration, tokcycle

My curiosity lies on mapping for transliteration. I am working on a project that uses transliteration. I have seen some solved code for this. But I could understand them. For example,

```
\def\tcmapto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\tcmapnumto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\tcremap#1{\ifcsname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname
                 \csname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname\else#1\fi}
```

**Question:** How these three lines work part by part. Can anyone elaborate with patience. Thank you.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\def\tcmapto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\tcmapnumto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\tcremap#1{\ifcsname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname
                 \csname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname\else#1\fi}

\tcmapto{ং}{n}% OR \tcmapnumto{2434}{n}
\tcmapto{আ}{Ā}% OR \tcmapnumto{2438}{Ā}
\tcmapto{ন}{n}% OR \tcmapnumto{2472}{n}
\tcmapto{ব}{b}% OR \tcmapnumto{2476}{b}
\tcmapto{ম}{m}% OR \tcmapnumto{2478}{m}
\tcmapto{র}{ra}% OR \tcmapnumto{2480}{ra}
\tcmapto{ল}{l}% OR \tcmapnumto{2482}{l}
\tcmapto{স}{s}% OR \tcmapnumto{2488}{s}
\tcmapto{া}{ā}% OR \tcmapnumto{2494}{ā}
\tcmapto{ো}{ō}% OR \tcmapnumto{2507}{ō}

\begin{document}
\Characterdirective{\addcytoks[x]{\tcremap{#1}}}
\tokencyclexpress
আমার সোনার বাংলা

আ-মা-র  সো-না-র  বাং-লা
\endtokencyclexpress
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wrote a generic answer on how to understand code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621577/250119). Hope it helps. (disclaimer: I wrote that answer)

Comment: In this particular case reading only the TeXBook is sufficient. (plus the documentation of that package being used)

Comment: The only thing to add to gernot's fine answer, is that the token-cycle proceeds through the input stream token by token. Macros and space tokens are echoed to the output directly, whereas character tokens are each subjected to `\tcremap`, in turn.  Group tokens are retained, while the tokens within the group are also processed individually through the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `` \def\tcmapto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname{#2}} ``

defines `\tcmapto` in such a way that each call of the form `\tcmapto{A}{B}` defines a command with the name

```
\tcpmapto<character code of A>
```

that expands to `B`. This way `\tcmapto` stores the transliteration of `A` to `B` in the new macro `\tcpmapto<character code of A>`. As an example,

```
\tcmapto{a}{b}
```

defines the command `\tcmapto97` that will expand to `b` (`97` is the character code of `a`).

- `\def\tcmapnumto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto#1\endcsname{#2}}`

does the same, but `\tcmapnumto` takes the character code itself as the first argument, instead of the character. As an example,

```
\tcmapnumto{97}{b}
```

also defines the command `\tcmapto97` that will expand to `b`.

- `` \def\tcremap#1{\ifcsname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname\csname tcmapto\number`#1\endcsname\else#1\fi} ``

`\tcremap{A}` checks whether a macro `\tcmapto<character code of A>` exists and, if it does, executes it. Otherwise it outputs `A`. The effect is that `\tcremap{A}` transliterates `A` to `B`, if this transliteration has been set up, or outputs `A`.

---

The basic building blocks.

- `\csname ... \endcsname` constructs a command name from whatever comes inbetween, expanding macros on the way. `\csname` is useful when defining unusual macro names, like those with digits in it.
- `\def\macroname{expansion}` defines the macro `\macroname` to expand to `expansion`.
- `\expandafter\def\csname ... \endcsname` means: First expand `\csname ... \endcsname` to get the macro name, and then define it. Without `\expandafter`, `\def` would redefine the macro name `\csname` itself.
- `\ifcsname ... \endcsname <then branch> \else <else branch> \fi`: If the characters between `\ifcsname` and `\endcsname` are the name of an existing macro, do the `<then branch>`, otherwise do the `<else branch>`.
- `` \number`<character> `` expands to the code of `<character>`

Comment: Thank you for explaining my code so well.