# LaTeX making a hidden table

Tags: tables

I am using one of the template from overleaf, but I want to customize a bit, I look up some documentation online, still not able understand. Can anyone explain what this code is about? All I know it is trying to make the hidden table.

```
\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
   #1&\parbox[t]{0.74\textwidth}{%
       \textbf{#2}%
    \hspace*{0pt}\hfill{\footnotesize#3}
    #4}
}
```

The twenty should hold 4 block from the table, right now it should be doing something like this

[image]

but what I am trying to do is

[image]

I am completely clueless if I can make something I am thinking of.

Edit :

```
\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions


\twentyitem{May 19 - Present}{Software Developer}{Company ABC}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item sentence A
    \item Sentence B
    \item Sentence C 
    \item Sentence D
    \item Sentence E
    \item Sentence F
\end{itemize}
```

}
[image]

This is what my original code have. I am trying to move block 4 to a bit of left, so it won't leave a lot of blank on the left side.

I am sorry that I could not be able to find the originate template. I hope this is enough.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show a short compilable TeX code resulting in your screenshot? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Which template are you using on Overleaf?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like having a table entry span multiple columns?

Comment: Understanding LaTeX is usually hard -- I wrote a generic answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621577/250119 (in this case lookup in LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual)

Comment: For this particular question I guess you need `multicolumn`, but without a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) it's quite hard to tell.

Comment: Alternatively you can also rewrite the template from scratch, copy parts when you need (and actually understand them). Making a table isn't very hard, just use the tabular environment (no border by default)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be from the [Twenty Seconds Curriculum Vitae](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-curriculum-vitae/kfgsngtymkfj) template on Overleaf.

---

Set the list inside a `minipage` and then precede it with a negative horizontal width:

[image]

```
\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
\twentyitem{since 05/21}{Software Developer}{Company ABC}{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Sentence A
      \item Sentence B
      \item Sentence C
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
}
\twentyitem{since 05/21}{Software Developer}{Company ABC}{%
  \hspace*{-2em}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Sentence D
      \item Sentence E
      \item Sentence F
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{twenty}
```

You can adjust `2em` to suit your needs, depending on how far you want to push the content into the margin.