# The function and meaning of variable \@afterindenttrue

Tags: latex-base

I do not know the function and meaning of variable `\@afterindenttrue` (see figure below). What will change if I change it to `\@afterindentfalse`, how can I see its changes? Thank you very much.

[image]

```
\def\@tocrmarg{2em}

\def\@dotsep{1} % 

\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%

\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else

\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@

{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip

\parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue

\interlinepenalty\@M

\leavevmode

\@tempdima #3\relax

\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip

{\csname thu@toc@font\endcsname #4}\nobreak

\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill

\nobreak{\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%

\par}%

\fi}
```

Comment: I can not see any change when I change the \@afterindenttrue with  \@afterindentfalse, which place does this command control?

Comment: Please never ever post images of code.

Comment: Look up `@afterindent` in `source2e`, https://texdoc.org/serve/source2e/0

Comment: I have seen the definition of \@afterindenttrue but  I still do not understand which place this command control, I commented this command, but its output is the same, no change at all

Comment: That is why I asked you to search that string, then you can see where it is used. It is an if statement

Comment: it shows nothing at all, only code, can you tell me where it control? thank you!

Comment: It controls (or rather is part of a control) that controls whether a following paragraph is indented or not see the code of the `indentfirst` package that makes the first paragraph after a section heading be indented

Comment: By  the way [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/)  for later reference

Comment: && [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thank you Prof. Carlisle, I want to know why it does not indent if I replace the orginial code in indentfirst.sty with \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindentfalse \@afterindenttrue and still set \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue?? what is the wrong?   The default value of \@afterindent is false, am I right?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle in other words, if I delete the statement \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue in your indentfirst.sty file, even if write \@afterindenttrue,  the first paragraph following the section still does not indent? why?

Comment: sorry the question really doesn't hav an answer `\@afterindenttrue` just makes `\if@afterindent` mean `\iftrue` tha is all it does. If you have some later code that has `\if@afterindent`  then i will take the true branch, if you do no have such code then i will do nothing..  This seems to be an XY Question, raher than ask what one single command taken from thousands of lines of latex source does, perhaps you should ask your real question, say what you wan to do and ask how to do it.