# Unable to show the macro/command definition, when the macro/command defined with optional argument

Tags: expl3, optional-arguments, meaning

For example, I define two commands. `\mytesta` with optional argument, `\mytestb` without optional argument. Now using `\cs_meaning:N` to show the command definition. The result is like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mytesta}[2][]{#2\quad#1}
\newcommand{\mytestb}[2]{#1\quad#2}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \checkmeaning \cs_meaning:N
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Large
\section{Testing}
\par\mytesta[default]{argument}
\par\mytestb{argument}{default}

\vskip 2em
\par\verb|\mytesta:|
{\par\ttfamily\checkmeaning \mytesta}
\par\verb|\mytestb:|
{\par\ttfamily\checkmeaning \mytestb}

\vskip 2em
\par\verb|Is possible to show:|
\par\verb|"[#1]#2->#2\quad #1" in \mytesta?|
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? The command is *really* defined like that. If you want to show the latter then show the command with csname `\mytesta` (you need to know some catcode manipulation to show that)

Comment: Alternatively just use latexdef, if what you really want to do is to show the definition of an existing command.

Comment: @user202729 I want to check the definition of some existing commands in certain packages. But it turn out that if the command is defined with optional argument,  I unable to see the latter definition.

Comment: @Tom Use `\ShowCommand\yourcommand`.  It will print the full definition in the terminal

Comment: @Phelype Thank you, is possible to print them in the document? As said by user202729 might need some catcode manipulations with csname or something?

Comment: @Tom For the particular case of macros defined with `\newcommand` and an optional argument, you can do `\cs_new:Npn\checkmeaning#1{\cs_meaning:c{\token_to_str:N#1}}`.  I don't know... Maybe a `\CommandMeaning` would be useful...

Comment: @Phelype It works. Thank you so much.

Comment: [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/)

Comment: As I mentioned in a previous comment, latexdef (see linked answer) could already resolve through those "standard" indirect layers.

Comment: Why you want show in document? Just go to source code and copy paste the definition (also have proper linebreak)

Comment: @user202729 You are right. There are a lot ways to see them.