# What is the "backslash greater than" command for?

Tags: macros, symbols

To make my life easier, I have defined the following two commands:

```
\newcommand{\<}{\langle}
\renewcommand{\>}{\rangle}
```

However, as you can see, the latter one required a redefinition, rather than a new definition. I tried to look for its definition, but it's not listed among other special escaped characters in various lists online (among these: `# $ % & ~ _ ^ \ { }`). Plus, the command itself doesn't actually print anything when I use it.

I work in Overleaf. Will something bad happen if I redefine it like this?

Comment: `tabbing` environment

Comment: There's [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/) but in this case latex2e.pdf Unofficial LaTeX reference manual is probably the best one