# What does `NewDocumentCommand \sidenote { o o +m }` mean?

Tags: macros

I have obviously missed some updated information about specifying LaTeX commands What I am used to is along the lines of

```
\newcommand{<command-name>}[<numargs>][<default>]{<command definition>}
```

and now I have seen that there is a definition like

```
\NewDocumentCommand \sidenote { o o +m }
```

which means nothing to me and which has no obvious relationship to the way I have specified new commands for the last 3 or so decades.

Where can I find out about this complete change in the command definition facilities and, possibly, why weren't there any obvious announcements about it?

I am on the comp.text.tex newgroup and I run TeXlive 2021 but am waiting for the DVD to arrive before updating to 2022.

Comment: you find the documentation with `texdoc xparse`. `o o +m` means three argument, two optional and  one mandatory which can be long.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You want to answer (perhaps including `usrguide(3)`)?

Comment: it's newish in the format but been available as the xparse package for a decade or so and some versions of this form have been available for longer than that: xparse.dtx has copyright dates going back as far as 1999

Comment: I think perhaps what you missied is that one no longer needs to explicitly include the line `\usepackage{xparse}` to make use of `\NewDocumentCommand{}{}`.  So, if you see this in code you need to look at the `xparse` documentation. It is actually much easier to control parameters with `xparse`, once you learn it, and only need to read a few pages of documentation.  The older `\newcommand` still works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would you like to make this an answer?

Comment: Special case of [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/), I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's newish in the format (October 2020) but has been available as the `xparse` package for a decade or so and some versions of this form have been available for longer than that: `xparse.dtx` has copyright dates going back as far as 1999.

The new code in the format is documented in `texdoc source2e` chapter g (ltcmd) although more convenient is the updated user guide (currently `texdoc usrguide3` although we will probably merge this back with `usrguide`soon)

`\NewDocumentCommand \sidenote { o o +m }{...#1 ... #2 ... #3}`

defines `\sidenote` with two optional arguments and one mandatory argument.
The `+` here denotes a `\long` argument that may accept blank lines (`\par`) like using `\newcommand` rather than `\newcommand*` except that `\NewDocumentCommand` allows this to be separately specified for each argument.

So
`\sidenote[a][b]{main}`
which can not easily be defined using `\newcommand`, which only allows declaration of a single optional argument.

In general the new features of each release are described in `ltnews`

`texdoc ltnews`

shows a pdf with the full series, you want LaTeX News 32 (2020/10) which documents this.

Comment: @campa done....

Comment: Wow! `texdoc ltnews` produced over 70 page detailing LaTeX improvements.