# Where/how is twocolumn option defined?

Tags: two-column

The question is pretty straightforward: Where (in which file) and how is the `twocolumn` option for latex classes defined?

This is what I found searching `article.cls`, just in case:

```
Linha  96:   \DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@twocolumnfalse}
    Linha  98: \DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}
    Linha  98: \DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue}
    Linha 210:       \if@twocolumn
    Linha 214:           \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
    Linha 322: \if@twocolumn
    Linha 331: \if@twocolumn
    Linha 378:       \if@twocolumn
    Linha 387:       {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
    Linha 412:       \if@twocolumn
    Linha 420:     {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
    Linha 425:       \if@twocolumn
    Linha 433:     {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
    Linha 587:                {\if@twocolumn
    Linha 592:                 \twocolumn[\section*{\indexname}]%
    Linha 635: \if@twocolumn
    Linha 636:   \twocolumn
```

*Note*: I had already searched it, of course.

What I mean is, what does `\@twocolumntrue`/false point to?

Comment: Have you looked at say `article.cls`? Just search for `twocolumn`. Twocolumn is a feature of the output routine, the classes then provides options to switch this feature on an off.

Comment: Special case of [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined). ■ specifically it's in `texdoc classes` which is mentioned in the top answer there.

Comment: I know the classes have options to switch it on/off, and yes, I looked at classes.pdf, which have the "switchers", but not the def. itself -- what do you mean as "feature of the output routine"? where do i find this "feature"?

Comment: @user574859 the idea is that you locate the file `article.cls` (for example using `kpsewhich article.cls` from a terminal), then open that file in an editor, then search for the string `twocolumn`, there you see how the option is defined and handled.

Comment: @Marijn, see updated question and comment above.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but the boolean flag `@twocolumn` that is being set to `true` with the class option is defined in `latex.ltx` (which is loaded by default when you compile with `pdflatex` or `xelatex` or `lualatex`, although in a precompiled form), in my version on line 15060 `\newif \if@twocolumn   \@twocolumnfalse`. Is that what you are asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the same directory as `article.cls` you will see a file `latex.ltx` and on line 16090 (of the current version) is

```
\def \twocolumn {%
  \clearpage
  \global\columnwidth\textwidth
  \global\advance\columnwidth-\columnsep
  \global\divide\columnwidth\tw@
  \global\hsize\columnwidth
  \global\linewidth\columnwidth
  \global\@twocolumntrue
  \global\@firstcolumntrue
  \col@number \tw@
  \@ifnextchar [\@topnewpage\@floatplacement
}
```

Together with multiple tests

```
\if@twocolumn
```

All over the file.

This is the source of the latex format, a typeset version including code level comments is obtained by

`texdoc source2e`