# What's the \synctex primitive? Where is it documented?

Tags: forward-inverse-search, e-tex

The question is in the title.

(needless to say I tried `texdoc synctex|etex_man|pdftex|pdftex-a|xetex|luatex` and the only thing I found is that it's enabled by the `extraprimitives` function in LuaTeX. And it looks like one of the internal number registers, but documentation should ideally/hopefully include e.g. can we turn it on and off during the compilation itself/between pages, etc.)

Comment: With some quick testing it appears that locally setting `\synctex=0` will not stop the file from being included in the final synctex output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extensions.c` in the luatex source has

```
int synctexoption;

/*tex

    A convenient primitive is provided: \.{\\synctex=1} in the input source file
    enables synchronization whereas \.{\\synctex=0} disables it. Its memory
    address is |synctex_code|. It is initialized by the {\sl Sync\TeX} controller
    to the command-line option if given. The controller may filter some reserved
    bits.

    In order to give the {\sl Sync\TeX} controller read and write access to the
    contents of the \.{\\synctex} primitive, we declare |synctexoffset|, such
    that |mem[synctexoffset]| and \.{\\synctex} correspond to the same memory
    storage. |synctexoffset| is initialized to the correct value when quite
    everything is initialized.

*/

/*tex Holds the true value of |synctex_code|: */
```

unlike say the primitive corresponding to `shell-escape`) it is not read-only and may be set locally.

Comment: Given that (if I recalled correctly) the ability to typeset TeX in comments in the source code has not been restored since the source code is converted from web to C, I think this is all there is. Other engine source code may have similar things.

Comment: @user202729 `texdoc pdftex-changes` (and `texdoc xetex-changes`) has the above quote typeset, in the current version on page 215.