# what is definition of "\@nobreaktrue"?

Tags: macros, catcodes

I find it difficult to find the definition of commands starting with `@`. Where and how is `\@nobreaktrue` defined?

Comment: your title asks about one specific command but the body asks about all commands starting @ . in package @ is a letter so asking about all commands starting @ is like asking about all commands starting k and has no real answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, i improved explaining of question

Comment: I'll mark [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/) as answering this one because the first answer there points out source2e, which solves this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX has a build in primitive `\show` to show the meaning of a command sequence. For example

```
\show\TeX
\bye
```

in plainTeX writes:

```
> \TeX=macro:
->T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX.
l.1 \show\TeX
```

to the terminal and the `log`-file.

But for LaTeX commands, that has been defined robust, this only show, something not very useful:

```
\show\pagebreak
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

results in the terminal (and the `log`-file) output:

```
> \pagebreak=macro:
->\protect \pagebreak  .
```

Because of this, LaTeX from release 2020-10-01 has a new command `\ShowCommand` (see `ltnews32.pdf`).

```
\ShowCommand\pagebreak
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

shows:

```
> \pagebreak=robust macro:
->\protect \pagebreak  .

> \pagebreak =\long macro:
->\@testopt {\@no@pgbk -}4.
<argument> \pagebreak
```

Which is more useful.

Note: The `<argument> \pagebreak` in the output above does not mean, that `\pagebreak` is a argument of `\pagebreak`, but that the `\ShowCommand` has been run with argument `\pagebreak`. I'm explaining this, to avoid misunderstanding the output. Real arguments would be shown as `#1` etc. before the `->`.

To show a command sequence starting with `@` you have to use [`\makeatletter…\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do):

```
\makeatletter
\ShowCommand\@nobreaktrue
\makeatother
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

writes to the terminal (and into the `log`-file):

```
> \@nobreaktrue=macro:
->\global \let \if@nobreak \iftrue .
```

Because `\@nobreaktrue` is not robust,

```
\makeatletter
\show\@nobreaktrue
\makeatother
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

has the same output.

BTW: To find out, where a definition has been done, you can only move the `\ShowCommand`. In the examples above all definitions can be found in the used formats. For example for `\ShowCommand\section` before `\documentclass` you would get `\section=undefined`. So you would know, that it is not a command of the LaTeX format. After loading the class, you would get another output and you'd know, that it is defined either in the class itself or a package required by the class.

To find a definition you could also search over the whole TEXMF tree, e.g., using `grep -R '\\@nobreaktrue' /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/*` in a Linux/Unix terminal. However, this would show not only the definition but also every usage. So you would need to restrict the search results more. In case of `\@nobreaktrue` doing

```
grep -R '\\def\\@nobreaktrue' /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/*
```

would result in:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx:\def\@nobreaktrue {\global\let\if@nobreak\iftrue}
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/latex.ltx:\def\@nobreaktrue {\global\let\if@nobreak\iftrue}
```

But, i.e., for `\@footrue` usually searching for a regular expression like `\\newif *\\if@foo[^@a-zA-Z]` is the better choice.