Where is the macro \hour defined in upLatex?
When I write the following code, and compile it by UpLaTex, all is well.
\documentclass{utbook}
\begin{document}
\hour\time 
\the\hour
\end{document}

But when I want to find the exact definition of the \hour, there is no definition in the source code there as the following forms:
\def\hour#1{\newcount\hour \hour=#1 }

Are there any other imexplicit definition of \hour in the source code? Or this already exists in LaTex?

In plcore.ltx you'll find \newcount\hour

@mbert, Thanks for your informing.

BTW: A definition like yours would be a bad idea, because it would allocate a new counter register for every usage of \hour. Another note: If you are interested in the definition instead of the place of definition you can use \show\hour (TeX) resp. \ShowCommand\hour (LaTeX). The result can be found in the terminal output and the log file. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/675996/277964 (and the links there).

Running an interactive session with uplatex, I see
This is e-upTeX, Version 3.141592653-p4.1.1-u1.30-230214-2.6 (utf8.uptex) (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=uplatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode
pLaTeX2e <2023-02-14u04>+1, based on
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>

*\show\hour
> \hour=\count191.
<*> \show\hour

which means that \hour is defined as a TeX counter (not a LaTeX counter). This is done in plcore.ltx, that's input when the uplatex format is made.
Thus your code
\hour\time

stores the current value of \time (a primitive integer register) into \hour and
\the\hour

just prints the value (in standard radix ten notation). Also the counter \minute is created.
The standard pLaTeX classes, in your case utbook.cls, do something with thess counters:
\hour\time \divide\hour by 60\relax
\@tempcnta\hour \multiply\@tempcnta 60\relax
\minute\time \advance\minute-\@tempcnta

Hence you have always available the hour and minute that were current when a uplatex run started.
\documentclass{utbook}
\begin{document}

Hour: \the\hour

Minute: \the\minute

\end{document}

The class also uses \hour and \minute for the tombow option (look at the documentation for it).

