# How do I search the hidden TeX Live folders in Mac OS X?

Tags: documentation, mactex

I considered asking this on Super User, and I also thought that TeX users on the Mac would be better able to help and be helped. I'll let the mods decide.

I opened `texdoc color` and came to `grfguide.pdf`. I am greeted with this:
[image]
I understand that all default TeX Live packages are installed in a "protected" folder. Using another app (called Afloat), I found out that `grfguide.pdf` can be found in `/usr/local/texlive...`

I will want to "process the `dtx` files" to see further documentation. Now, Spotlight doesn't search the protected folders. I won't be able to just type in `sty` or `dtx` or `ins`. How do I search the TeX Live folders on a Mac?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grepping through an entire texmf tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/grepping-through-an-entire-texmf-tree)

Comment: This is quite different to that previous question.

Comment: How is it different? Do `.sty`, `.dtx` and `.ins` files not live inside the texmf tree?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary to compile those files since compiled versions are already included in TeX Live. Say

```
texdoc -l color
```

to get access to all parts of the documentation. In this case, select the second document (`color.pdf`) which is the "developer part" of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks to Philipp's posting on the texdoc list, I added aliases so that, starting with the next texdoc update in texlive/mactex, `texdoc color-dev` will give you the developer doc for color (and similarly for graphics, graphics, and epsfig).

Of course, using the `-l` switch when you're not satisfied with the first result is always a good habit.

Comment: Huh. In MiKTeX, when you run `texdoc foo` (which is actually an alias for `mthelp foo` or something, I think) and `foo` has more than one document to choose from, it opens an HTML page listing all of the choices in the default browser. I'm not sure I'm too thrilled with this; sometimes I don't like what my browser will do when I click on one, and sometimes I don't notice that it's done this and wonder what's taking so long. (Though there is a `--view` flag that will take you straight to the first one, as well as the `-l` flag you mention, so it's not really a problem either way.)

Answer (score 3):

I rather strongly suspect that the reason spotlight doesn't index the texlive folder is that it is inside `/usr`, which has the "invisible" Finder flag set. You can turn that flag off with `xattr`, but maybe you don't want to index *all* of `/usr`. In which case you could use `xattr` to set the invisible flag on all subdirectories of `/usr` except `/usr/local`, and then turn off the one on `/usr`. Something like this:

```
xa="`xattr -px com.apple.FinderInfo /usr`"
for d in /usr/*; do xattr -wx com.apple.FinderInfo "$xa" "$d"; done
xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo /usr
xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo /usr/local
```

A much simpler fix would be to move `/usr/local/texlive` to a new place and insert a symlink in the original location. That might give you trouble when you wish to install texlive 2011, though, unless you remember to move it back first. So playing around with `xattr` seems safer. (The only documentation of `xattr` seems to be the one you get by running `xattr --help`.

Comment: +1, I am certain your reasoning is correct, and I've used this trick myself (usually to hide things from Spotlight).  I recommend /Users/Shared/texlive as the target of the symlink.  I can't think of any reason why installing the new Texlive across this symlink would cause problems: it's a completely standard technique used by UNIX sysadmins.  The only thing to watch for is permissions.

Comment: @Charles, then maybe we could suggest that future versions of TeX Live to be installed in a Spotlight-accessible folder?

Comment: @Kit: I wouldn't like that. I want things to be in exactly the same place on both my Mac OSX and Linux machines. Doing just this is high up on the things I like about the way Texlive does things.

Comment: @Charles, I could try out your method then. It looks good just as well. Blame my suggestion on my limited experience `:)`

Comment: What, no `xattr(1)` or `xattr(8)`? What kind of lousy excuse for a *nix ... wait, what are you talking about, there is so an [`xattr(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html)! (Now what I want to know is how Google found a page with a `#` in the URL...)

Comment: @SamB: Okay, so there's an xattr(1) on the web, but it's not included with the system. The man page doesn't hold a any more information than the `--help` output anyhow. Apple's habit of looking at the bit after the # to decide what contents to serve has had me puzzled too, as it seems to skirt the boundaries of how http is supposed to work. But evidently, google's search robot is aware of this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The most GUI-friendly way is to navigate to `/Library/TeX/Documentation` (or perhaps 
`/Library/TeX/Root`) and then use the Finder's search box to find what you're interested in.

Access to these "hidden" folders is enabled with symlinks for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have a Mac. Maybe `locate .dtx` works. If not, you might try `find /usr -name '*.dtx'` (both on the command line, the second command might be somewhat slow as it doesn’t use an index).

Comment: Yes, `locate` works fine on a Mac; this is how I routinely find source of installed packages when I want to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

They should be in something like

```
/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/source/
```

Using `find` from that path should be able to help you find them.
In particular the ones you're looking for are under `latex/graphics`.