# Where can I find LaTeX and its package installation guide in details?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, linux, books, documentation

After some days when my university will be closed for vacation of [Eid al-Fitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Fitr) I will go to my village (InshaAllah).

I have decided to learn LaTeX in the vacation. But in my village there is no Internet connection. So, if I will fail to install any package in that time I can not take help from Internet. For this, I am downloading all packages that may be needed.

And I also need some manuals/books/documents about package installation, so that if I will fail to install any package I can overcome it by reading the documents.

Which books/manuals/documents you recommend me for taking with me?

No problem if the document's size is high.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and fedora 25 as OS and I use TeX Live.

Comment: when you install LaTeX the package documentations should be installed, too. You can access them from the command line with the `texdoc` command. For example `texdoc tikz`.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some more information what aspects of LaTeX you want to learn, or which field your studies are in, such that we can provide further information for useful resources.

Comment: Ah, and by the way: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @jjdb, are you wanting to know about my subject? My subject is CSE.

Comment: Sorry, CSE says nothing to me. Could you maybe orient on the [standard categories of science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Science/Categories_and_Main_topics) (if it applies), or at least the broad categories one uses in [SE](https://stackexchange.com/sites)? Or try some other general description in what context you want to use LaTeX?

Comment: @jjdb, sorry. Now, I understand your question. I am such a person that when I know/get(or love any tool) any benefit of a tool I make a habit to use this tool in all sector. I love vim and I also know some benefit of it's, so I use vim for all sort of text editing(except if the  java project is so big I go to netbeans). I know about some(may be less) benefit of LaTeX and I also love LaTeX, so I want to use this for all sort of documents writing, it may be SE document, Numerical document or any lab report also.

Comment: @jjdb I mean SE as software engineering not Stack Exchange.

Comment: So you probably would like also to learn how to include source code and draw some graphs? So I'm not very familiar with the former so that I would not recommend any specific packages or documentation. But for the latter, have a look at the very sophisticated `tikz` documentation, and also `pgfplots` if you need to plot data (performance whatever).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The full TeXLive installation comes with the documentation of its packages, usually under the path `/usr/local/texlive/2016/tex-dist/doc/`.

The full installation takes about 4Gb, and is easiest done via the `install-tl` script that can be found [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). More information how to install in this way can be found in this related question

- [How to install vanilla-TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In the documentation you can find various helpful LaTeX introductions, such as

- `firstlatexdoc` which shows you to get your first document
- `lshort` which gives you a very good introduction into various aspects
- `latex4wp` which has a focus on word processor users
- `latexcheat` a cheat sheet overview
- `l2tabu` an overview of bad practices
- `latex-doc-ptr` an overview where to find more information
- `latex2e-help-texinfo` the (un-)official reference manual
- `comprehensive` an overview of an abundance of symbols and commands
- …

You can directly load the corresponding `pdf` of the documentation by typing e.g. `texdoc lshort` on the command line.

Furthermore, as these documentation documents include their `.tex` sources, you can even search the documentation via `grep`, or using the [following script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/grepping-through-an-entire-texmf-tree/4089#4089).

You can find more information concerning references and documentation on the [TeX Users Group web site](https://www.tug.org/begin.html) or their [links to further documentation](https://www.tug.org/interest.html#doc), where you can also find recommendations for books and where you can download numerous resources.

Also have a look at the related question for more information, where you can find numerous links to pdf-files and Ebooks available for download:

- [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner/)

Another good resource is the [TeX Catalogue](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html), which I prefer in the form of a [Topical Index](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html). Here you can also find a list of packages that might be interesting for your purpose, eg. for [Computer science](http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html#cs). It might be sufficient to just download or even print this list, as you need only the package names to find them in the documentation tree of TeXLive.

Comment: I installed TeXLive from tug.org and also got the documentation for each package about 2694 package.

Comment: is it possible to add extra documentation in the same directory when I will install new packages?

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Yes, of course. But it's best you use `tlmgr` to install new packages. You can look up the list of all available packages by typing `tlmgr list | more` in the command line, and install a not-installed package (without an *'i'* in front; I chose `boldtensors`) by `tlmgr install boldtensors` (maybe add a `sudo` in front), et voilà, the documentation for `boldtensors` is there. Removing the package, `tlmgr remove boldtensors` removes the package and also the documentation. `tlmgr` is a really nice tool, however I didn't find a question here promoting its pros. I'll add one

Comment: are all [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg) packages available in `tlmgr`?

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Actually, as far as I understand it, tlmgr draws its installation files from a specific CTAN mirror. You can see the repositories currently used by `tlmgr repository list`

Comment: That means there are may be more package untouched by `tlmgr`. Am I right?. Thank you, jjdb you helped me a lot.

Comment: Yes, at least everything not included in CTAN… and maybe also some CTAN packages, see the comment by @daleif below my related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368703/28751

Answer (score 3):

=================

For windows

=================

https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex

```
                or
```

https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html

=================

For Linux

=================

https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html

==================

Complete LaTeX package both Windows and Linux

==================

http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2016.iso

Comment: I would suggest you to download texlive-2016 huge iso which does not require internet connection to install latex packages, 1). Install Texlive -2016, 2). Install any latex Editor eg. Texmaker, winedit, texstudio etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu: type `Ctrl-Alt-T` to get a command line. Type `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` to get a complete tex installation. This includes documentation using the command line command `texdoc`. You might like to have some books on TeX as well, for example Knuth's **The TeXbook**.

Comment: I would not recommend installing from the OS repository via `apt-get` or similar tools, as these might not be shipping out the current version of TeXLive. Also, the keyboard shortcut you've mentioned  depends on the window manager, and it might be specific to Gnome (probably).

Comment: See for the [downsides of OS package manager installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200209/what-are-the-benefits-of-vanilla-texlive-over-texlive-provided-by-ubuntu-reposit?noredirect=1&lq=1)