# How to find the right package

Tags: packages, latex-misc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find a package name by a command name?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/how-to-find-a-package-name-by-a-command-name)

Sorry to ask such a simple question, but I wonder if there is any listing or any site that I can easily find the package for a command. For instance I want to use '\includegraphics{}' but I don't know how to find the appropriate package to use. This question applies in the other way as well. If I want to know what are the functions inside a package.

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this one too. Googling does not seem to work too well, because most documentation is hidden away in attached pdf files.

Comment: This question was asked (and answered) in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3777/1235) (possible duplicate).

Comment: you don't need a package to use `\mathcal`: it just needs to be inside mathmode: `$\mathcal{X}$` works fine without any packages...

Comment: I have written 'for example'. :D Ok I edit it to something more real.

Comment: This is difficult, I agree. Google was my friend, but the TeX world is *big* and finding the right way to do things can be very difficult.

Comment: How about an example of a command where googling doesn't work? First hit on google for "LaTeX \includegraphics" mentions the package to use...

Comment: I don't think that is the right method. Currently I am doing it this way, I download samples from google per command and to make this process easier, I copy lots of \usepackage commands to every document I make. But I doubt, it is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm running into such problems, the commands are mostly very exotic (not like includegraphics). 
I use the [CTAN network package search](http://tug.ctan.org/search.html#byDescription) to find a overview of packages which are delivering the desired macro. It's faster than google but not perfect :) I use the third text box on the linked site.