# Getting to a command definition

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined)

Is there a more or less general and (hopefully) convenient way to learn what is a command encountered in a source file?

Let's take a few lines right at the beginning of book.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{book}
          [2007/10/19 v1.4h
          Standard LaTeX document class]
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\newif\if@restonecol
\newif\if@titlepage
\@titlepagetrue
\newif\if@openright
\newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue
\if@compatibility\else
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
```

The subject question applies literally to every line:

- What is `\ProvidesClass` and how to look it up?
- What is `\newif` and how to look it up?
- What is `\DeclareOption` and how to look it up?

I'd like to know where exactly the better known `\newcommand` is declared, for that matter.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Since thes are serval questions which can all be answerd by reading a good book about LaTeX (e.g. the [LaTeX Companion](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/LaTeX-Companion-The/9780201362992.page)) or google them and then coming back with a more detailed question if there is a thing your book/google left out or didn’T answer …

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`texdef`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) too look up the definitions as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31123/5701.

Comment: I don't think `texdef` is going to help someone understand what `\ProvidesClass` is doing…

Comment: Now that this question has been migrated to tex.sx, perhaps you should either elaborate on your answer or (in case the question is a real duplicate) convert your answer to Community Wiki or a comment.

Comment: @lockstep I have converted it to community wiki make it easier for others to fill in.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way is to use `show`. From the command line start pdflatex interactively:

```
% pdflatex
* \documentclass{book}
* \show\ProvidesClass
> \ProvidesClass=macro:
#1->\xdef \@gtempa {#1}\ifx \@gtempa \@currname \else \@latex@warning@no@line {
You have requested \@cls@pkg \space `\@currname ',\MessageBreak but the \@cls@p
kg \space provides `#1'}\fi \@ifnextchar [\@pr@videpackage {\@pr@videpackage []
}.
<*> \show\ProvidesClass
```

Comment: Again, `\show` is just thoroughly unhelpful for a command like `\ProvidesClass`.

Comment: Well you are correct. It is good for some commands, but `\ProvidesClass` is not one of them. In general I think the best way to find LaTeX2e definitions is in the commented source itself. Here is an online version http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf  and here is a hardcover version. http://www.lulu.com/product/hardcover/latex-sources/971405 Although it has an author listed, that is just the person who uploaded the pdf.