# Italics in LaTeX

Tags: packages

Which package must you include to use the italics command `\textit{}`?

More generally, if I find a command I would like to use (in a tutorial, for example), how can I easily identify which package I must include to use the command?

Comment: Hi, welcome. You don't need any additional package for `\textit`. Your more general question was asked earlier, so perhaps you can find some useful info in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3777

Comment: From the following MWE you can see that no additional packge is needed to use the `\textit` command: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text \textit{italic text}
\end{document}`

Comment: If the tutorial is good then it also contains information on the packages that are needed, if any.

Comment: Welcome to tex.stack....

Comment: Technically, it’s defined by the LaTeX kernel, but that would only be relevant if you wanted to use plain TeX.

Comment: Generally you should not use `\textit{}` but `\emph{}` that have a semantic meaning instead of a formatting meaning ("text to be **emph**asized" instead of "**text** to be **it**alized"). It seems a bit stupid because  the method of emphasizing is use italics, , but note that  `\textit{l\textit{l}l}` will produce simply " *lll* " whereas `\emph{l\emph{l}l}` will produce " *l*l*l* " (i.e,  emphasized upright text within and already emphasized text with italics) which could have sense in some contexts. Moreover, one ot them should not be redefined, guess which one?

Answer (score 3):

`\textit, \textrm, \textbf` and `\textsf` are the primitive commands in LaTeX, these tags never expect any packages, if you need any text should be in bold with italic face, then should use the tag as `\textbf{\textit{...}}`... Hope this may helpful to you...

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/textit.htm may helps you...