# Command already defined. How to find the bad definition?

Tags: macros

I have `atm1.tex` which used to compile ok.  It hasn't changed since last time I compiled it, but its base classes have changed:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \text already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

How can I find where `\text` was already defined?

`atm1.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{atm}
...
\begin{checklist} % Makes a table where we can add \text, \result, or \action lines
  \text{This line contains text}
  ...
```

`atm.cls` contains:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{atm}[acceptance test manual template]

\LoadClass{simdoc}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{simdoc}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{textcomp} % Allows use of degree symbol
\RequirePackage[clock]{ifsym} % Brings in \StopWatchStart
...
\newcommand{\text}[1]{& #1 & &\\}
...
```

and `simdoc.cls` contains:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{simdoc}[Sim International document template]

\LoadClass{report}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{longtable,array}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{textcomp, booktabs}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{soul}
\RequirePackage [most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
...
```

Clearly `\text` is defined in `atm1.cls`, and that's the only one I expected would exist.  I suspect someone added a new `\RequirePackage` to `simdoc.cls` which introduces a new definition for `\text`. I could rename `\text` to something else, but I have hundreds of documents which inherit from this class (all broken) and thousands of uses of `\text`, so I'd rather not change all of them.

I tried changing `\newcommand{\text}` to `\providecommand{\text}`.  It compiles, but it doesn't seem to use `atm.cls`'s definition of `\text` (instead of a `\text{Hello}` taking up a line in the table, it overlaps the next line of the table).

I also tried: `\let\text\undefined\newcommand{\text}...`.  This works, but is it safe?  I'm scared about unintended consequences.

If the above idea is not safe, then my question is "how do I know which `\RequirePackage` defined `\text`?".  Knowing this will help me search for alternatives.

Comment: `\text` is defined in `amsmath`, I'd strongly recommend not to redefine it.

Comment: Did you know `\text` was defined in `amsmath` by memory, or did you figure this out so quickly with a command or search?

Comment: By memory. It is a widely used command. Searching in packages is more cumbersome.

Comment: Never redefine macros unless you know exactly what they do and what they are used for. Choose a different name. The classic example is `\span`, hardly anyone knows what it is used for, so it would be obvious to redefine it to be `\operatorname{span}` if you're writing about linear algebra. If you do that tables, matrices, align, etc no longer works.  `\text` has been in `amstext` which is loaded by `amsmath` for many many years. The only way this has been able to compile is if `amsmath` has never been used.

Comment: apart from the question that \text is already defined in amsmath, your definition doesn't look like something that a class should provide. A command to create an empty line in a tabular with four columns is much to specific.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The class provides `\newenvironment{checklist}` which defines a table.  Then these commands are meant for use within that table.  The table is pretty fundamental for the hundreds of documents which use this class.  If I want to add a signature column to the table or prefix a reference number, I just have to change the class instead of the hundreds of documents.  That's exactly what a class is for isn't it?

Comment: While that answers a good part of the question, two issues still remain: (a) _**How can I find** where `\text` was already defined?_ and the other (not so explicitly stated) (b) **What to do with those** _hundreds of documents which inherit from this class (all broken) and thousands of **uses of \text**_ ?  ░░░  The second one could be done with a global file(s) replace using an utility like `sed` on Linux.  The first one was posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4327/146828), ...but probably this [`grep` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3792/146828) could be the best way out !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Dangerous bend sign]

Since your `\text` is only used inside the `checklist` environment, you *could* redefine it from the `amsmath` version within that environment.

In `atm.cls`:

```
\newcommand{\atm@text}[1]{& #1 & &\\}

\newenvironment{checklist}{%
   \let\text\atm@text%
   % rest of environment begin code
}{% environment end code }
```

The `\let` control sequence will override LaTeX's redefinition prevention mechanisms.  Because each environment is contained in its own TeX group, once the environment ends, `\text` will snap back to its `amsmath` definition.

The drawback is that you will not be able to use the `amsmath` version of `\text` inside the `checklist` environment.  You could give it another name with the same `\let` pattern, but that won't be enough if some other command uses it indirectly.

Comment: I really like this answer, because it's solves the core of my problem.  If I want to keep the simplicity that comes with a 4-letter command, changing the names won't alleviate risk of another name clash.  Indeed the `checklist` environment is very restrictive and so this scope-limited override is perfect!

Answer (score 6):

`\text` is defined by `amsmath` (or rather by the `amstext` package that is included by `amsmath`). You will find thousands of examples on this site and defining it with a separate definintion will break most mathematical documents as they will almost all include `amsmath`

However to answer the question of how to find the package that defines a command, you can ask latex to show the current definition, or search the sources.

For the first,  the document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\text{zzz}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Shows an error on the terminal:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \text already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.11 \newcommand\text{zzz}
```

But if you modify it it:

```
\show\text
\documentclass{article}
\show\text
\usepackage{graphicx}
\show\text
\usepackage{color}
\show\text
\usepackage{amsmath}
\show\text
\usepackage{hyperref}
\show\text
\newcommand\text{zzz}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

Then the terminal output is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./aa274.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-05-07>
> \text=undefined.
l.1 \show\text
              
? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> \text=undefined.
l.3 \show\text
              
? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
> \text=undefined.
l.5 \show\text
              
?
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
> \text=undefined.
l.7 \show\text
              
? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
> \text=macro:
->\protect \text  .
l.9 \show\text
              
? 
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def
) (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
)))
> \text=macro:
->\protect \text  .
l.11 \show\text
               
? 

! LaTeX Error: Command \text already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12 \newcommand\text{zzz}
?
```

Which clearly shows `\text` is undefined until `amsmath` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks!  This is a good answer to this problem which I am sure to run into again (probably not with `\text` next time).

Comment: FYI, The definition of `\text` came from `\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}` which must import `amsmath`.  We never included `amsmath` directly.  This answer definitely helped me to figure that out.