# Database of command names for all TeX Live macros

Tags: api

The command `latexdef -l -p amsmath` gives all the macros created by `amsmath`.

Has anyone used it to build a command name "database" for all `TeX Live` macros? If not, I will build a basic `JSON` file.

### Why?

This could help `LaTeX` developers to avoid, in their API, name conflicts, or to indicate them.

Comment: Maybe [macros - How to find a package name by a command name? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/how-to-find-a-package-name-by-a-command-name) ? there's a new thing there.

Comment: if contemplating adding a command, or finding use of command I just do grep -r '\\ccmd' /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex

Comment: This kind of command is not very useful. Try for example `grep -r '\\then' /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex`. It will be not hard to just build all the names-packages-classes found by combining in a long time-consuming combination of `tlmgr list --only-installed` , `latexdef -l -p ...` and `latexdef -l -p ...` .

Comment: often we want to know where it is used, not just where it is defined, eg "will making this command robust break existing packages" means finding every use. Search for `\\then\b` if you want `\then` but not `\thenormalizedbodyfontsize`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is a good thing. I'll think about it, but I'd like to avoid name conflicts first before coding.

Comment: Try `\next` and see what happens

Comment: @egreg My idea is just to avoid name conflict. The `\next` gives a lot of lines, but that can be still useful using a dedicated tool.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but there's [`texfindpkg`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texfindpkg) which uses texstudio completion files as a command list. Still has issues to work out though (see the discussion in the chat [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex#c158169))

Comment: Considering that just one package as `todonotes` that have just a few user commands, this display also many not documented commands for internal use and of all the dependencies, but over all, that three are 6402 packages in CTAN,  and increasing,   .... in one word:  ouch! 

Comment: This is why I think about a DB.